# Splitting a list into N parts of approximately equal length

Tags: python, list, chunks

What is the best way to divide a list into *roughly* equal parts? For example, if the list has 7 elements and is split it into 2 parts, we want to get 3 elements in one part, and the other should have 4 elements.

I'm looking for something like `even_split(L, n)` that breaks `L` into `n` parts.

```
def chunks(L, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from L.
    """
    for i in range(0, len(L), n):
        yield L[i:i+n]
```

The code above gives chunks of 3, rather than 3 chunks.  I could simply transpose (iterate over this and take the first element of each column, call that part one, then take the second and put it in part two, etc), but that destroys the ordering of the items.

Comment: See [Bresenham's line-drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) for exactness.

Comment: I once [asked about such splits](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3652905/654489), which could be a reference if you're interested in the split indices.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**This code is broken due to rounding errors. Do not use it!!!**

```
assert len(chunkIt([1,2,3], 10)) == 10  # fails
```

---

Here's one that could work:

```
def chunkIt(seq, num):
    avg = len(seq) / float(num)
    out = []
    last = 0.0

    while last < len(seq):
        out.append(seq[int(last):int(last + avg)])
        last += avg

    return out
```

Testing:

```
>>> chunkIt(range(10), 3)
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
>>> chunkIt(range(11), 3)
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
>>> chunkIt(range(12), 3)
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

Comment: Your example won't work for ```>>> chunkIt(range(8), 6)``` =>
```[[0], [1], [2, 3], [4], [5], [6], [7]]```

Comment: @nopper, I added an "if num == 1:" conditional to handle that edge case.

Comment: New visitors: **please don't use or upvote this code**, it's broken.  e.g. `chunkIt(range(10), 9)` should return 9 parts, but it doesn't.

Comment: @wim it seems like it is returning the correct values. Are you still facing any issues with this implementation?

Comment: I added `if num > len(seq):  num = len(seq)` at the start of the function.

Comment: This comment thread is really confusing as the answer has been edited several times. Is this a good answer? Not a good answer?

Comment: @conchoecia Not a good answer, keep scrolling down. This was just edited once so far, and it was only a trivial edit (2 space indent changed to 4). Unfortunately the OP "user248237dfsf" hasn't been seen on the site for over 3 years, so there is little hope of getting the accepted answer changed.

Answer (score 336):

You can write it fairly simply as a list generator:

```
def split(a, n):
    k, m = divmod(len(a), n)
    return (a[i*k+min(i, m):(i+1)*k+min(i+1, m)] for i in range(n))
```

Example:

```
>>> list(split(range(11), 3))
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: Insert `n = min(n, len(a)) # don't create empty buckets` on line 1 to avoid creating empty buckets in scenarios like `list(split(range(X, Y)))` where `X < Y`

Comment: Seeing as I can't edit my comment -- I should add that my previous amendment could possibly raise a division by zero error if the list is empty, so that needs to either be controlled externally or added to the solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37414115/210971 uses the same method, but works also for empty list and 0 split counter.

Comment: Beautiful! Also, n can be made to work as  batch_size by swapping k and n in the return statement :)

Comment: this solution is better than the accepted answer, since it splits list into equal-ish chunks for all chunks.  
the accepted answer has the potential to have 1 item in its last list.

Comment: works very well! I personally changed it to a generator for convenience: `def split(lst, n):
    k, m = divmod(len(lst), n)
    for i in range(n):
        yield lst[i*k+min(i, m):(i+1)*k+min(i+1, m)]
`

Comment: Is the result of the lists always show up as sorted?

Answer (score 281):

This is the *raison d'être* for [`numpy.array_split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html)*:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print(*np.array_split(range(10), 3))
[0 1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]
>>> print(*np.array_split(range(10), 4))
[0 1 2] [3 4 5] [6 7] [8 9]
>>> print(*np.array_split(range(10), 5))
[0 1] [2 3] [4 5] [6 7] [8 9]
```

<sub>*credit to [Zero Piraeus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36387103#36387103) in room 6</sub>

Comment: What's the `*` in `print` for?

Comment: Hey @yuqli, It converts a list of something into individual arguments to a function.  try `print(L)` and `print(*L).  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/2184122 or search for "python use of asterisk".

Comment: [x.tolist() for x in np.array_split(range(10), 3)]

Comment: This and the more_itertools answer is the only reasonable thing to do in a modern language. This is always my problem with python, everything seems half finished. Why isn't something lke this part of the standard library?

Comment: way more standartized then the other answer

Comment: Also works for pandas series

Comment: Careful - this might cast your item values if they're not the same data type (e.g. list of (str, int) tuples)!

Comment: @Max That's a good point. I guess converting input array explicitly with `np.array(L, dtype=object)` could prevent it in that case.

Answer (score 136):

As long as you don't want anything silly like continuous chunks:

```
>>> def chunkify(lst,n):
...     return [lst[i::n] for i in xrange(n)]
... 
>>> chunkify(range(13), 3)
[[0, 3, 6, 9, 12], [1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11]]
```

Comment: I wouldn't say continuous chunks are silly. Perhaps you'd like to keep the chunks sorted (ie. chunk[0] < chunk[1]), for instance.

Comment: I was kidding. But if you really didn't care, this way with list comprehension is nice and concise.

Comment: This is subscripting with a *stride of n*

Comment: sending this output into 'zip' gives you your ordered list: `zip(*chunkify(range(13), 3))` results in `[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11)]`

Comment: This solutions works fine, until you need order of list the stay same.

Comment: Along with @gens comment, this is brilliant!

Comment: @gens comment looses uneven elements (12)

Comment: @Adirio use `itertools.zip_longest` to end up with an extra tuple with the 12 in it

Comment: another way in py2 is to map with None: `map(None, *chunkify(range(13), 3))` which gives `[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11), (12, None, None)]`

Comment: @gens , nope! then it deletes the last items. try: `s = [0,1,2,3, 4,5,6,7, 8,9,10,11,  12,13,14]`  with 4 chunks  .. from 12, 13, 14 will be discarded.

Comment: This also more evenly distributes the number of items. With the other methods the number of items in splits would be `5 5 3` whereas this one is `5 4 4`. This is great for splitting up work between processes or threads for example since it distributes work more evenly

Answer (score 29):

If you divide `n` elements into roughly `k` chunks you can make `n % k` chunks 1 element bigger than the other chunks to distribute the extra elements.

The following code will give you the length for the chunks:

```
[(n // k) + (1 if i < (n % k) else 0) for i in range(k)]
```

*Example: `n=11, k=3` results in `[4, 4, 3]`*

You can then easily calculate the start indizes for the chunks:

```
[i * (n // k) + min(i, n % k) for i in range(k)]
```

*Example: `n=11, k=3` results in `[0, 4, 8]`*

Using the `i+1`th chunk as the boundary we get that the `i`th chunk of list `l` with len `n` is

```
l[i * (n // k) + min(i, n % k):(i+1) * (n // k) + min(i+1, n % k)]
```

As a final step create a list from all the chunks using list comprehension:

```
[l[i * (n // k) + min(i, n % k):(i+1) * (n // k) + min(i+1, n % k)] for i in range(k)]
```

*Example: `n=11, k=3, l=range(n)` results in `[range(0, 4), range(4, 8), range(8, 11)]`*

Comment: Instead of `1 if i < (n % k) else 0)` would `n % 2` be equivalent?

Comment: @Blundell No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 21):

Changing the code to yield `n` chunks rather than chunks of `n`:

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield n successive chunks from l.
    """
    newn = int(len(l) / n)
    for i in xrange(0, n-1):
        yield l[i*newn:i*newn+newn]
    yield l[n*newn-newn:]

l = range(56)
three_chunks = chunks (l, 3)
print three_chunks.next()
print three_chunks.next()
print three_chunks.next()
```

which gives:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
[18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
[36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]
```

This will assign the extra elements to the final group which is not perfect but well within your specification of "roughly N equal parts" :-) By that, I mean 56 elements would be better as (19,19,18) whereas this gives (18,18,20).

You can get the more balanced output with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield n successive chunks from l.
    """
    newn = int(1.0 * len(l) / n + 0.5)
    for i in xrange(0, n-1):
        yield l[i*newn:i*newn+newn]
    yield l[n*newn-newn:]

l = range(56)
three_chunks = chunks (l, 3)
print three_chunks.next()
print three_chunks.next()
print three_chunks.next()
```

which outputs:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
[19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37]
[38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]
```

Comment: this gives me a strange result. for p in chunks(range(54), 3): print len(p) returns 18, 18, 51...

Comment: Fixed, that, it was the final yield.

Comment: see also a solition at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17749743/python-split-a-list-into-x-number-of-chunks?lq=1)

Comment: This is the most useful answer for practical considerations. Thanks!

Comment: When I use this, doing `for x in chunks(mylist,num): print x`, I get the desired chunks, but between them I get an empty list.  Any idea why?  That is, I get lots of `[]`, one after each chunk.

Comment: Useful, nitpick: fails if `n > len(l)`, added a special case for that, `if len(l) < n: return [[x] for x in l]`

Answer (score 15):

This will do the split into equal parts by one single expression while keeping the order:

```
myList = list(range(18))  # given list
N = 5  # desired number of parts

[myList[(i*len(myList))//N:((i+1)*len(myList))//N] for i in range(N)]
# [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16, 17]]
```

The parts will differ in not more than one element. The split of 18 into 5 parts results in 3 + 4 + 3 + 4 + 4 = 18.

Answer (score 11):

See [`more_itertools.divide`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.divide):

```
n = 2

[list(x) for x in mit.divide(n, range(5, 11))]
# [[5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]

[list(x) for x in mit.divide(n, range(5, 12))]
# [[5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

Install via [`> pip install more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools).

Answer (score 7):

Here is one that adds `None` to make the lists equal length

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield n successive chunks from l. Pads extra spaces with None
    """
    return list(zip(*izip_longest(*[iter(l)]*n)))

>>> l=range(54)

>>> chunks(l,3)
[(0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48, 51), (1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34, 37, 40, 43, 46, 49, 52), (2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35, 38, 41, 44, 47, 50, 53)]

>>> chunks(l,4)
[(0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52), (1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 33, 37, 41, 45, 49, 53), (2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22, 26, 30, 34, 38, 42, 46, 50, None), (3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 39, 43, 47, 51, None)]

>>> chunks(l,5)
[(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50), (1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36, 41, 46, 51), (2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47, 52), (3, 8, 13, 18, 23, 28, 33, 38, 43, 48, 53), (4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, 34, 39, 44, 49, None)]
```

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [numpy.split](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
>>> a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> numpy.split(a, 2)
[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])]
```

Comment: And numpy.array_split() is even more adequate because it roughly splits.

Comment: This doesn't work if the array size isn't divisible by the number of splits.

Comment: This is wrong answer, your solution returns list of ndarrays, not list of lists

Answer (score 7):

Using list comprehension:

```
def divide_list_to_chunks(list_, n):
    return [list_[start::n] for start in range(n)]
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of making all the chunks even.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a generator that can handle any positive (integer) number of chunks. If the number of chunks is greater than the input list length some chunks will be empty. This algorithm alternates between short and long chunks rather than segregating them.

I've also included some code for testing the `ragged_chunks` function.

```
''' Split a list into "ragged" chunks

    The size of each chunk is either the floor or ceiling of len(seq) / chunks

    chunks can be > len(seq), in which case there will be empty chunks

    Written by PM 2Ring 2017.03.30
'''

def ragged_chunks(seq, chunks):
    size = len(seq)
    start = 0
    for i in range(1, chunks + 1):
        stop = i * size // chunks
        yield seq[start:stop]
        start = stop

# test

def test_ragged_chunks(maxsize):
    for size in range(0, maxsize):
        seq = list(range(size))
        for chunks in range(1, size + 1):
            minwidth = size // chunks
            #ceiling division
            maxwidth = -(-size // chunks)
            a = list(ragged_chunks(seq, chunks))
            sizes = [len(u) for u in a]
            deltas = all(minwidth <= u <= maxwidth for u in sizes)
            assert all((sum(a, []) == seq, sum(sizes) == size, deltas))
    return True

if test_ragged_chunks(100):
    print('ok')
```

---

We can make this *slightly* more efficient by exporting the multiplication into the `range` call, but I think the previous version is more readable (and DRYer).

```
def ragged_chunks(seq, chunks):
    size = len(seq)
    start = 0
    for i in range(size, size * chunks + 1, size):
        stop = i // chunks
        yield seq[start:stop]
        start = stop
```

Answer (score 7):

Let's say you want to split a list **[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]** into 3 element lists

like **[[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]**, where if the last remaining elements left are less than 3, they are grouped together.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
my_list2 = [my_list[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(my_list), 3)]
print(my_list2)
```

**Output:** *[[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]*

Where length of one part is 3. Replace 3 with your own chunk size.

Comment: This is an elegant answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution:

```
def chunks(l, amount):
    if amount < 1:
        raise ValueError('amount must be positive integer')
    chunk_len = len(l) // amount
    leap_parts = len(l) % amount
    remainder = amount // 2  # make it symmetrical
    i = 0
    while i < len(l):
        remainder += leap_parts
        end_index = i + chunk_len
        if remainder >= amount:
            remainder -= amount
            end_index += 1
        yield l[i:end_index]
        i = end_index
```

Produces

```
    >>> list(chunks([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3))
    [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 6):

The other solutions seem to be a bit long. Here is a one-liner using list comprehension and the NumPy function `array_split`. `array_split(list, n)` will simply split the `list` into `n` parts.

```
[x.tolist() for x in np.array_split(range(10), 3)]
```

Comment: Answer's are great. But for best practices, please provide an explanation (Saying things like 'here' or 'elegant' or 'try this' do not count). You only posting code makes the OP and future commers copy and paste your answer without understanding the logic behind the answer. Please provide an answer with some explanation. Thank You!

Answer (score 4):

Implementation using numpy.linspace method.

Just specify the number of parts you want the array to be divided in to.The divisions will be of nearly equal size.

Example :

```
import numpy as np   
a=np.arange(10)
print "Input array:",a 
parts=3
i=np.linspace(np.min(a),np.max(a)+1,parts+1)
i=np.array(i,dtype='uint16') # Indices should be floats
split_arr=[]
for ind in range(i.size-1):
    split_arr.append(a[i[ind]:i[ind+1]]
print "Array split in to %d parts : "%(parts),split_arr
```

Gives :

```
Input array: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
Array split in to 3 parts :  [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([6, 7, 8, 9])]
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution, easy to understand

```
def split_list(lst, n):
    splitted = []
    for i in reversed(range(1, n + 1)):
        split_point = len(lst)//i
        splitted.append(lst[:split_point])
        lst = lst[split_point:]
    return splitted
```

And shortest one-liner on this page(written by my girl)

```
def split(l, n):
    return [l[int(i*len(l)/n):int((i+1)*len(l)/n-1)] for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: FYI: Your one-liner is broken, yields wrong results. The other one works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be something like this, the idea here is to use grouper, but get rid of `None`. In this case we'll have all 'small_parts' formed from elements at the first part of the list, and 'larger_parts' from the later part of the list. Length of 'larger parts' is len(small_parts) + 1. We need to consider x as two different sub-parts.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

import numpy as np

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None): # This is grouper from itertools
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

def another_chunk(x,num):
    extra_ele = len(x)%num #gives number of parts that will have an extra element 
    small_part = int(np.floor(len(x)/num)) #gives number of elements in a small part

    new_x = list(grouper(small_part,x[:small_part*(num-extra_ele)]))
    new_x.extend(list(grouper(small_part+1,x[small_part*(num-extra_ele):])))

    return new_x
```

The way I have it set up returns a list of tuples:

```
>>> x = range(14)
>>> another_chunk(x,3)
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11, 12, 13)]
>>> another_chunk(x,4)
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12, 13)]
>>> another_chunk(x,5)
[(0, 1), (2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7), (8, 9, 10), (11, 12, 13)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variant that spreads the "remaining" elements evenly among all the chunks, one at a time until there are none left. In this implementation, the larger chunks occur at the beginning the process.

```
def chunks(l, k):
  """ Yield k successive chunks from l."""
  if k < 1:
    yield []
    raise StopIteration
  n = len(l)
  avg = n/k
  remainders = n % k
  start, end = 0, avg
  while start < n:
    if remainders > 0:
      end = end + 1
      remainders = remainders - 1
    yield l[start:end]
    start, end = end, end+avg
```

For example, generate 4 chunks from a list of 14 elements:

```
>>> list(chunks(range(14), 4))
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13]]
>>> map(len, list(chunks(range(14), 4)))
[4, 4, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

The same as [job's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2136090/3712360) answer, but takes into account lists with size smaller than the number of chuncks.

```
def chunkify(lst,n):
    [ lst[i::n] for i in xrange(n if n < len(lst) else len(lst)) ]
```

if n (number of chunks) is 7 and lst (the list to divide) is [1, 2, 3] the chunks are [[0], [1], [2]] instead of [[0], [1], [2], [], [], [], []]

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
split=lambda x,n: x if not x else [x[:n]]+[split([] if not -(len(x)-n) else x[-(len(x)-n):],n)][0]

split([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],2)

[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python


first_names = ['Steve', 'Jane', 'Sara', 'Mary','Jack','Bob', 'Bily', 'Boni', 'Chris','Sori', 'Will', 'Won','Li']

def chunks(l, n):
for i in range(0, len(l), n):
    # Create an index range for l of n items:
    yield l[i:i+n]

result = list(chunks(first_names, 5))
print result
```

Picked from this [link](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/break_list_into_chunks_of_equal_size/), and this was what helped me. I had a pre-defined list.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def evenly(l, n):
    len_ = len(l)
    split_size = len_ // n
    split_size = n if not split_size else split_size
    offsets = [i for i in range(0, len_, split_size)]
    return [l[offset:offset + split_size] for offset in offsets]
```

**Example:**

`l = [a for a in range(97)]` should be consist of 10 parts, each have 9 elements except the last one.

**Output:**

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
 [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
 [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
 [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
 [45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53],
 [54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62],
 [63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71],
 [72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80],
 [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
 [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96]]
```

Answer (score 1):

1>

```
import numpy as np

data # your array

total_length = len(data)
separate = 10
sub_array_size = total_length // separate
safe_separate = sub_array_size * separate

splited_lists = np.split(np.array(data[:safe_separate]), separate)
splited_lists[separate - 1] = np.concatenate(splited_lists[separate - 1], 
np.array(data[safe_separate:total_length]))

splited_lists # your output
```

2>

```
splited_lists = np.array_split(np.array(data), separate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def chunkify(target_list, chunk_size):
    return [target_list[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(target_list), chunk_size)]

>>> l = [5432, 432, 67, "fdas", True, True, False, (4324,131), 876, "ofsa", 8, 909, b'765']
>>> print(chunkify(l, 3))
>>> [[5432, 432, 67], ['fdas', True, True], [False, (4324, 131), 876], ['ofsa', 8, 909], [b'765']]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a single function that handles most of the various split cases:

```
def splitList(lst, into):
    '''Split a list into parts.

    :Parameters:
        into (str) = Split the list into parts defined by the following:
            '<n>parts' - Split the list into n parts.
                ex. 2 returns:  [[1, 2, 3, 5], [7, 8, 9]] from [1,2,3,5,7,8,9]
            '<n>parts+' - Split the list into n equal parts with any trailing remainder.
                ex. 2 returns:  [[1, 2, 3], [5, 7, 8], [9]] from [1,2,3,5,7,8,9]
            '<n>chunks' - Split into sublists of n size.
                ex. 2 returns: [[1,2], [3,5], [7,8], [9]] from [1,2,3,5,7,8,9]
            'contiguous' - The list will be split by contiguous numerical values.
                ex. 'contiguous' returns: [[1,2,3], [5], [7,8,9]] from [1,2,3,5,7,8,9]
            'range' - The values of 'contiguous' will be limited to the high and low end of each range.
                ex. 'range' returns: [[1,3], [5], [7,9]] from [1,2,3,5,7,8,9]
    :Return:
        (list)
    '''
    from string import digits, ascii_letters, punctuation
    mode = into.lower().lstrip(digits)
    digit = into.strip(ascii_letters+punctuation)
    n = int(digit) if digit else None

    if n:
        if mode=='parts':
            n = len(lst)*-1 // n*-1 #ceil
        elif mode=='parts+':
            n = len(lst) // n
        return [lst[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(lst), n)]

    elif mode=='contiguous' or mode=='range':
        from itertools import groupby
        from operator import itemgetter

        try:
            contiguous = [list(map(itemgetter(1), g)) for k, g in groupby(enumerate(lst), lambda x: int(x[0])-int(x[1]))]
        except ValueError as error:
            print ('{} in splitList\n   # Error: {} #\n {}'.format(__file__, error, lst))
            return lst
        if mode=='range':
            return [[i[0], i[-1]] if len(i)>1 else (i) for i in contiguous]
        return contiguous

r = splitList([1, '2', 3, 5, '7', 8, 9], into='2parts')
print (r) #returns: [[1, '2', 3, 5], ['7', 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The same behavior like `numpy.array_split` written as a generator, and fast to understand:

```
def split(a, n):
    k, m = divmod(len(a), n)
    for i in range(n):
        size = k + 1 if i < m else k
        yield a[:size]
        a = a[size:]
```

Answer (score -1):

Rounding the linspace and using it as an index is an easier solution than what amit12690 proposes.

```
function chunks=chunkit(array,num)

index = round(linspace(0,size(array,2),num+1));

chunks = cell(1,num);

for x = 1:num
chunks{x} = array(:,index(x)+1:index(x+1));
end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I've written code in this case myself:

```
def chunk_ports(port_start, port_end, portions):
    if port_end < port_start:
        return None

    total = port_end - port_start + 1

    fractions = int(math.floor(float(total) / portions))

    results = []

    # No enough to chuck.
    if fractions < 1:
        return None

    # Reverse, so any additional items would be in the first range.
    _e = port_end
    for i in range(portions, 0, -1):
        print "i", i

        if i == 1:
            _s = port_start
        else:
            _s = _e - fractions + 1

        results.append((_s, _e))

        _e = _s - 1

    results.reverse()

    return results
```

divide_ports(1, 10, 9) would return

```
[(1, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9), (10, 10)]
```

Answer (score -1):

this code works for me (Python3-compatible):

```
def chunkify(tab, num):
    return [tab[i*num: i*num+num] for i in range(len(tab)//num+(1 if len(tab)%num else 0))]
```

example (for **bytearray** type, but it works for **list**s as well):

```
b = bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08')
>>> chunkify(b,3)
[bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x03'), bytearray(b'\x04\x05\x06'), bytearray(b'\x07\x08')]
>>> chunkify(b,4)
[bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'), bytearray(b'\x05\x06\x07\x08')]
```

Answer (score -1):

This one provides chunks of length <= n, >= 0

def

```
 chunkify(lst, n):
    num_chunks = int(math.ceil(len(lst) / float(n))) if n < len(lst) else 1
    return [lst[n*i:n*(i+1)] for i in range(num_chunks)]
```

for example

```
>>> chunkify(range(11), 3)
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]
>>> chunkify(range(11), 8)
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried most part of solutions, but they didn't work for my case, so I make a new function that work for most of cases and for any type of array:

```
import math

def chunkIt(seq, num):
    seqLen = len(seq)
    total_chunks = math.ceil(seqLen / num)
    items_per_chunk = num
    out = []
    last = 0

    while last < seqLen:
        out.append(seq[last:(last + items_per_chunk)])
        last += items_per_chunk

    return out
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def chunk_array(array : List, n: int) -> List[List]:
    chunk_size = len(array) // n 
    chunks = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(array):
        # if less than chunk_size left add the remainder to last element
        if len(array) - (i + chunk_size + 1) < 0:
            chunks[-1].append(*array[i:i + chunk_size])
            break
        else:
            chunks.append(array[i:i + chunk_size])
            i += chunk_size
    return chunks
```

here's my version (inspired from Max's)

Answer (score -1):

```
n = len(lst)
# p is the number of parts to be divided
x = int(n/p)

i = 0
j = x
lstt = []
while (i< len(lst) or j <len(lst)):
    lstt.append(lst[i:j])
    i+=x
    j+=x
print(lstt)
```

This is the simplest answer if it is known that the list divides into equal parts.

Answer (score -2):

say you want to split into 5 parts:

```
p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 = np.split(df, 5)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question, e.g. how would you write it if you don't know in advance that you want to split it in five pieces. Also, you are (I'm guessing) assuming numpy and maybe a pandas dataframe. The OP is asking about a generic list.

Answer (score -2):

If you don't mind that the order will be changed, I recommend you to use @job solution, otherwise, you can use this:

```
def chunkIt(seq, num):
    steps = int(len(seq) / float(num))
    out = []
    last = 0.0

    while last < len(seq):
        if len(seq) - (last + steps) < steps:
            until = len(seq)
            steps = len(seq) - last
        else:
            until = int(last + steps)
        out.append(seq[int(last): until])
        last += steps
return out
```

Answer (score -2):

Another attempt at simple readable chunker that works.

```
def chunk(iterable, count): # returns a *generator* that divides `iterable` into `count` of contiguous chunks of similar size
    assert count >= 1
    return (iterable[int(_*len(iterable)/count+0.5):int((_+1)*len(iterable)/count+0.5)] for _ in range(count))

print("Chunk count:  ", len(list(         chunk(range(105),10))))
print("Chunks:       ",     list(         chunk(range(105),10)))
print("Chunks:       ",     list(map(list,chunk(range(105),10))))
print("Chunk lengths:",     list(map(len, chunk(range(105),10))))

print("Testing...")
for iterable_length in range(100):
    for chunk_count in range(1,100):
        chunks = list(chunk(range(iterable_length),chunk_count))
        assert chunk_count == len(chunks)
        assert iterable_length == sum(map(len,chunks))
        assert all(map(lambda _:abs(len(_)-iterable_length/chunk_count)<=1,chunks))
print("Okay")
```

Outputs:

```
Chunk count:   10
Chunks:        [range(0, 11), range(11, 21), range(21, 32), range(32, 42), range(42, 53), range(53, 63), range(63, 74), range(74, 84), range(84, 95), range(95, 105)]
Chunks:        [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41], [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52], [53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62], [63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73], [74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83], [84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94], [95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104]]
Chunk lengths: [11, 10, 11, 10, 11, 10, 11, 10, 11, 10]
Testing...
Okay
```