# How to split a list into a given number of sub-lists in python

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [splitting a list of arbitrary size into only roughly N-equal parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130016/splitting-a-list-of-arbitrary-size-into-only-roughly-n-equal-parts)
>   [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

I need to create a function that will split a list into a list of list, each containing an equal number of items (or as equal as possible).

e.g.

```
def split_lists(mainlist, splitcount):
    ....


mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

`split_list(mylist,2)` will return a list of two lists of three elements - `[[1,2,3][4,5,6]]`.

`split_list(mylist,3)` will return a list of three lists of two elements.

`split_list(mylist,4)` will return a list of two lists of two elements and two lists of one element.

I don't care which elements appear in which list, just that the list is divided up as evenly as possible.

Comment: I thought this looked familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130016/splitting-a-list-of-arbitrary-size-into-only-roughly-n-equal-parts

Comment: This question and its companion "clever answer" using zip and iter() has come up about 5 times in the past 48 hours. Search is your friend.

Comment: search "python list chunks" and you'll find your answer... voting to close as duplicate

Comment: This question asks for splitting sequence into *specified number* of chunks, not the chunks of *specified length*. This is not the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

numpy.split does this already:

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html

Examples:

```
>>> mylist = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

> split_list(mylist,2) will return a list of two lists of three elements
>   - [[1,2,3][4,5,6]].

```
>>> np.split(mylist, 2)
[array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])]
```

> split_list(mylist,3) will return a list of three lists of two
>   elements.

```
>>> np.split(mylist, 3)
[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6])]
```

> split_list(mylist,4) will return a list of two lists of two elements
>   and two lists of one element.

You may probably want to add an exception capture for the cases when the remainder of length(mylist)/n is not 0:

```
>>> np.split(mylist, 4)
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 np.split(mylist, 4)
...
ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division
```

Comment: Really bad, doesn't answer the question, nor does it work.

Comment: I've added some examples to make the answer more clear. To be fair, the original questions is not very clear, but I think numpy.split does what the OP wants. At least the examples for n=2 and n=3 seem to return the same outputs as in the question (except that the output is a numpy array instead of a list, but I've assumed that this is not a problem)

Comment: Question asks "how to split a list" not a np array. But I reversed my downvote to up nevertheless.

Comment: For ex this works: 

`def split_list(alist, wanted_parts=1):
    length = len(alist)
    return [ alist[i*length // wanted_parts: (i+1)*length // wanted_parts]
             for i in range(wanted_parts) ]`

Comment: `np.array_split` has the same syntax and avoids the possibility of a `ValueError`