# Python List Division/Splitting

Tags: python, list, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

Hello,

I'm trying to find a simpler way to do the following:

```
def list_split(list, size):
  result = [[]]
  while len(list) > 0:
    if len(result[-1]) >= size: result.append([])
    result[-1].append(list.pop(0))
  return result
```

Example usage:

```
>>> list_split([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2)
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
>>> list_split([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3)
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
```

I can't tell if there's a built-in way to do this, possibly with slicing or something.

This is similar but not the same to the post at [How to split a list into a given number of sub-lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235526/how-to-split-a-list-into-a-given-number-of-sub-lists-in-python-closed)

Thanks

**EDIT**:
As is commented on by Anurag Uniyal, this is a duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python/312467#312467), and should be closed, which I cannot do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python/312467#312467

Comment: why other seemingly duplicate questions are not similar to your question?

Comment: sorry, when I was searching for it I wasn't quite sure what this could be called

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use slices to get subsets of a list.

Example:

```
>>> L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> n = 3
>>> [L[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(L), n)]
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
>>>
```

Comment: IMO this is the most Pythonic solution.

Comment: Yeah, actually, using range's step is a better way than my initial approach.

Comment: +1: Definitely the most explicit and clear way to split the list!  It's also probably faster than rebuilding sub-lists through list comprehensions.

Comment: Er, this is using a comprehension, EOL.

Answer (score 1):

```
def list_split(L, size):
    return [L[i*size:(i+1)*size] for i in range(1+((len(L)-1)//size))]
```

If you prefer a generator instead of a list, you can replace the brackets with parens, like so:

```
def list_split(L, size):
    return (L[i*size:(i+1)*size] for i in range(1+((len(L)-1)//size)))
```

Comment: Have you actually tried to run this code? Also, please don't name your parameter "list".

Comment: That doesn't work, list_split([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2) shouldn't return [[0, 1], [2], []]

Comment: Sorry, typo (forgot parens around `i+1`). Will fix.

Comment: (Kenny, the only reason for the parameter naming was to mirror the OP's defintion.)

Comment: Still doesn't work, list_split([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2) shouldn't return [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]] (see original post)

Comment: @Amber: OK, @CMC, please don't name your parameter "list".

Comment: @Amber: It works now
@KennyTM: I realize that list is a bad name for a variable, as it is also a type, but for the sake of readability, and simplicity I changed it to list.

Comment: Please rename `list` to `L`. It's a Pythonic parameter/variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple functional solution in the itertools recipes (*grouper*):

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes

Whereas this function adds padding, you can easily write a non-padded implementation taking advantage of the (usually overlooked) *iter* built-in used this way: `iter(callable, sentinel) -> iterator`

```
def grouper(n, it):
  "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG') --> ABC DEF G"
  return iter(lambda: list(itertools.islice(it, n)), [])

list(grouper(3, iter(mylist)))
```

These solutions are more generic because they both work with sequences and iterables (even if they are infinite).

Comment: N.B. If you forget the `iter` from `iter(mylist)`, then the iterator returned by `grouper` will never stop! So always pass an iterator to that function. If you pass a list named L, `islice(L, n)` will return the first N elements of L every time it's called. So unless L is empty, the `[]` sentinel will never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def list_split(L, size):
    return [[j for j in i if j is not None] for i in izip_longest(*[iter(L)]*size)]
```

---

```
>>> list_split([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2)
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
>>> list_split([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3)
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]]
>>> list_split([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 4)
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> list_split([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 5)
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: This is quite similar to the grouper() recipe of itertools, but the padding removal makes it look a bit convoluted.