# python store a split list into multiple files and items in same line

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a huge list with 9000 items. I already referred this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235526/how-to-split-a-list-into-a-given-number-of-sub-lists-in-python). Don't mark it as duplicate

```
Mylist = [1234,45678,2314,65474,412,87986,21321,4324,68768,1133,712421,12132,0898]
```

I would like to split my list and store the output of each list in a notepad file

For ex: I wish each of my output list to contain ~10% of items from the original `Mylist`

So, I tried the below

```
for k,g in itertools.groupby(Mylist, lambda x: x/10):
      with open("part1.txt", 'w') as file:
      file.write('\n'.join(yourList))
```

I expect my output to have multiple text files like below and each file should contain 10% of items stored like below in screenshot from original list

```
part1.txt
part2.txt
part3.txt
part4.txt
```

[image]

Comment: you use use slices not groupby

Comment: can help write as an answer? My code above is not working correctly. So, would be helpful if you can guide me to produce multiple text files as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `groupby`, a simple loop with slicing is sufficient. You need to decide how to handle the extra items (add to the last list or add an extra file):

```
Mylist = [1234,45678,2314,65474,412,87986,21321,4324,68768,1133,712421,12132,898]
N = 3 # use 10 in your real life example

step = len(Mylist)//N
start = 0
for i, stop in enumerate(range(step, len(Mylist)+step, step)):
    print(f'file{i}')
    print(Mylist[start:stop]) # save to file here instead
    start = stop
```

output:

```
file0
[1234, 45678, 2314, 65474]
file1
[412, 87986, 21321, 4324]
file2
[68768, 1133, 712421, 12132]
file3
[898]
```

Variant for adding to last file:

```
Mylist = [1234,45678,2314,65474,412,87986,21321,4324,68768,1133,712421,12132,898]
N = 3

step = len(Mylist)//N
start = 0

for i, stop in enumerate(range(step, len(Mylist), step)):
    print(f'file{i}')
    if i+1 == N:
        stop = len(Mylist)
    print(Mylist[start:stop]) # save to file here instead
    start = stop
```

output:

```
file0
[1234, 45678, 2314, 65474]
file1
[412, 87986, 21321, 4324]
file2
[68768, 1133, 712421, 12132, 898]
```

###### saving to file

```
Mylist = [1234,45678,2314,65474,412,87986,21321,4324,68768,1133,712421,12132,898]
N = 3

step = len(Mylist)//N
start = 0

for i, stop in enumerate(range(step, len(Mylist), step), start=1):
    if i == N:
        stop = len(Mylist)
    with open(f'file{i}.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(','.join(map(str,Mylist[start:stop])))
    start = stop
```

Comment: Can update your answer to include export to notepad file?

Comment: because when I export, each item in the list are stacked one by one. each item is in one line, But I want my output to look like how I have shown in screenshot above