# python multiprocessing queue error

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, eoferror

I have this python code to read a file, do some processing and write the results in parallel:

```
def line_chunker(path):
    """
    Reads a file in chunks and yields each chunk.
    Each chunk is guaranteed to end at a carriage return (EOL).
    Each chunk is returned a single string.

    The number of chunks the file is split into is equal to the number of CPU cores
    available
    """
    size = os.path.getsize(path)
    cores = mp.cpu_count()
    chunksize = size/cores # gives truncated integer

    f = open(path)
    s = f.readline() # skip header
    while True:
        part = f.readlines(chunksize)
        if not part:
            f.close()
            break
        else:
            yield "".join(part)
    f.close()

def _validate(chunk, outq):
    """ Performs format validation on a given chunk of a csv file """
    rows = csv.reader(StringIO(chunk))
    vld = validation.RowValidator(rows)
    vld.check_rows()
    outq.put(vld.errors)

def _write(outq):
    """Writes lines in the outq to a text file """
    outfile = open("C:/testoutput.txt", "w")
    while True:
        result = outq.get()
        if result is None:
            outfile.close()
            break
        else:
            for line in result:
                outfile.write(line)
                outfile.write("\n")

def validate_pll(path):    
    """ Perform validation in parallel """

    pool = mp.Pool()
    outq = mp.Manager().Queue(maxsize = 8)

    writer = mp.Process(target = _write, args = (outq,))
    writer.start()
    for chunk in line_chunker(path):
        pool.apply_async(_validate, (chunk, outq))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

It reads the file in chunks and for each chunk starts a process to do the processing. The results of the processing are put on a queue, which is watched by another process.

The code runs, but after completion I get an odd `EOFError`.

I suspect it is because I do not call `writer.join()`, but if I add this line, like so:

```
def validate_pll(path):    
    """ Perform validation in parallel """

    pool = mp.Pool()
    outq = mp.Manager().Queue(maxsize = 8)

    writer = mp.Process(target = _write, args = (outq,))
    writer.start()
    for chunk in line_chunker(path):
        pool.apply_async(_validate, (chunk, outq))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    writer.join()
```

The code simply hangs. 
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

The error message given is:

```
Process Process-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File C\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py, line 258, in _bootstrap
        self.run()
    File C\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\process.py line 114, in run
       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    File C:\SVN\PortfolioInspector\trunk\parallel.py, line 114 in _write
       result = outq.get()
    File "(string)", line 2, in get
    File C\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py, line 759, in _callmethod
        kind, result = conn.recv()
EOFError
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `_writer` process is still waiting for entries to be written to `outq` when the main process ends. It waits for entries by opening a blocking connection to the `Manager` process that manages the shared `Queue`. Now, at the point that  the main process completes its execution,  the `Manager` process shuts down, which sends the EOF to the connection that `_writer` opened, and you see that exception.

To fix it, you need to tell `_writer` to shut down prior to the main process ending (and by extension, the `Manager` process shutting down) . You actually already have a mechanism in place for this, you're just not using it; send a `None` to `outq`, and `_writer` will do an orderly shutdown. Call that prior to `writer.join()`, and things should work fine.

Comment: duh! of course. I think I thought that queue would automatically give None if there is nothing there, but of course if you call get() on an empty queue it just waits to have something to return. 

I added an ``outq.put(None)`` before ``pool.close()`` and it works fine now.

Comment: What if my outq is a dictionary ? Will sending a None to my dictionary still work ?