# python multiprocessing TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The following code errors out once in a while. It works fine if I start just one process. But I keep increasing the number of processes to, may be 11 and it starts throwing an error.

```
try:
    num_workers = int(sys.argv[1])
except:
    num_workers = 1

someval = 10
def do_work(in_queue,x):
    i = 0
    while True:
        item = in_queue.get()
        line_no, line = item

        # exit signal
        if line == None:
            if i > 0 :
                work.put(i,)
            # work.put(i)
            return
        else:
            print "value from work " + line.rstrip('\n')
            i = i + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":

    manager = Manager()
    work = manager.Queue(num_workers)
    someval = 20
    print " Number of workers is " + str(num_workers)
    pool = []
    for i in xrange(num_workers):
        p = Process(target=do_work, args=(work,someval))
        p.start()
        pool.append(p)
    with open("/home/jay/scripts/a.txt") as f:
         iters = itertools.chain(f, (None,)*num_workers)
         for num_and_line in enumerate(iters):
                work.put(num_and_line)

    x = 0
    for p in pool:
        p.join()
```

The file /home/jay/scripts/a.txt has 10 lines.

If I do

```
 ./x.py 7
     Number of workers is 7
    value from work 1
    value from work 2
    value from work 3
    value from work 4
    value from work 5
    value from work 6
    value from work 7
    value from work 8
    value from work 9
    value from work 10
     x is 0
     all done 

./x.py 11
 Number of workers is 11
value from work 1
value from work 2
value from work 3
value from work 4
value from work 5
value from work 6
value from work 7
value from work 8
value from work 9
value from work 10
Process Process-11:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./x.py", line 18, in do_work
    line_no, line = item
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
 x is 0
 all done
```

Comment: Add `print(repr(item))` before line 18 so you can know what the value is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offending line is `work.put(i,)` in `do_work`
You put `int` into the queue and that `int` gets read and unpacked by another worker.

Also I agree with dano that using multiprocessing.Pool is easier and shorter.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_workers)
    with open("/home/jay/scripts/a.txt") as f:
        mapped = pool.map(do_work, f)
```

If you need that `i` from the worker just return it and it will be stored in `mapped`

Comment: My real file is huge - more than 100 GB. As per another thread, "the map is going to consume your file all at once before dishing out work. " So I decided to take this approach. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196367/processing-single-file-from-multiple-processes-in-python

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `work.put(1,)` doesn't do what you think it does. You're intending to put the 1-tuple `(1,)` into the queue, but you're actually just putting `1` into the queue. If you change that line to `work.put((1,))` you'll see the behavior you expect.

There's a race condition with large values of `num_workers` that allows one of your sub-process to add the `1` to the queue before your for loop in the main process finishes loading the `Queue` up with the `(None,)` sentinel values. With smaller values of `num_workers`, you get through the for loop before any of the worker processes add the `1` to the queue.

Also, have you considered using `multiprocessing.Pool`, rather manually creating a `Pool` using `Process` and `Queue`? It would simplify your code quite a bit.