# Why does multiprocessing.Lock() not lock shared resource in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Supposing I have a very big text file consisting of many lines that I would like to reverse. And I don't care of the final order. The input file contains Cyrillic symbols. I use `multiprocessing` to process on several cores.

I wrote such program:

```
# task.py

import multiprocessing as mp


POOL_NUMBER = 2


lock_read = mp.Lock()
lock_write = mp.Lock()

fi = open('input.txt', 'r')
fo = open('output.txt', 'w')

def handle(line):
    # In the future I want to do
    # some more complicated operations over the line
    return line.strip()[::-1]  # Reversing

def target():
    while True:
        try:
            with lock_read:
                line = next(fi)
        except StopIteration:
            break

        line = handle(line)

        with lock_write:
            print(line, file=fo)

pool = [mp.Process(target=target) for _ in range(POOL_NUMBER)]
for p in pool:
    p.start()
for p in pool:
    p.join()

fi.close()
fo.close()
```

This program fails with error:

```
Process Process-2:
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "task.py", line 22, in target
    line = next(fi)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 0: invalid start byte
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "task.py", line 22, in target
    line = next(fi)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

On the other hand, everything works fine if I set `POOL_NUMBER = 1`. But it doesn't make a sense if I want to gain the total performance.

Why does that error happen? And how can I fix it?

I use `Python 3.5.2`.

I generated data using this script:

```
# gen_file.py

from random import randint


LENGTH = 100
SIZE = 100000


def gen_word(length):
    return ''.join(
        chr(randint(ord('а'), ord('я')))
        for _ in range(length)
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('input.txt', 'w') as f:
        for _ in range(SIZE):
            print(gen_word(LENGTH), file=f)
```

Comment: You can refer to an answer about [Processing single file from multiple processes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11196615/4662041)

Comment: did you try to read that file and print its data? if you catch that error again! that means you should read it, as binary mode with "rb" ...

Comment: @DRPK I did. If I drop `line = handle(line)` from my script, the same error comes.

Comment: which line you get this error?

Comment: `line = next(fi)`

Comment: @DPPK I extended the details about the error. I would be happy if you have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is reading a file from multi processes isn't working as you think, you can't share the `open` object between processes.

You could make a global `current_line` variable, and each time read the file and process the current line, not ideal.

Here is a different approach, using processes pool, and `map` method, I'm iterating over the file, and for each line I enqueue your target method:

```
from multiprocessing import Lock
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import os

POOL_NUMBER = 8

def target(line):
    # Really need some processing here
    for _ in range(2**10):
        pass
    return line[::-1]


pool = Pool(processes=POOL_NUMBER)
os.truncate('output.txt', 0)  # Just to make sure we have plan new file
with open('input.txt', 'r') as fi:
    t0 = time.time()
    processed_lines = pool.map(target, fi.readlines())
    print('Total time', time.time() - t0)

    with open('output.txt', 'w') as fo:
        for processed_line in processed_lines:
            fo.writelines(processed_line)
```

With 8 process on my machine:
`Total time 1.3367934226989746`

And with 1 process:
`Total time 4.324501991271973`

This works best if your target function is CPU bound, a different approach would be to split the file into `POOL_NUMBER` chunks and make each process write a processed chunk of data(with lock!) to the output file.

Another approach, is to create a master process that does the write job for the rest of the processes, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446445/python-multiprocessing-safely-writing-to-a-file) is an example.

**EDIT**

After you comment i figured you can't fit the file into memory.
For this, you can just iterate over the file object which will read line by line into memory. But than we need to modify the code a little big:

```
POOL_NUMBER = 8
CHUNK_SIZE = 50000

def target(line):
    # This is not a measurable task, since most of the time wil spent on writing the data
    # if you have a CPU bound task, this code will make sense
    return line[::-1]


pool = Pool(processes=POOL_NUMBER)
os.truncate('output.txt', 0)  # Just to make sure we have plan new file
processed_lines = []

with open('input.txt', 'r') as fi:
    t0 = time.time()
    for line in fi:
        processed_lines.append(pool.apply_async(target, (line,)))  # Keep a refernce to this task, but don't 

        if len(processed_lines) == CHUNK_SIZE:
            with open('output.txt', 'w') as fo:  # reading the file line by line
                for processed_line in processed_lines:
                    fo.writelines(processed_line.get())
            processed_lines = []  # truncate the result list, and let the garbage collector collect the unused memory, if we don't clear the list we will ran out of memory!
    print('Total time', time.time() - t0)
```

Keep in mind that you can play with the `CHUNK_SIZE`  variable to control how much memory you use. For me 5000 is about 10K max for each process.

**P.S**

I think it would be best the split the big file into smaller files, this way you solve the read/write lock on the file, and also make it scalable to process(even on a different machine!)

Comment: Thank you for the solution you provided. But unfortunately it has a big disadvantage. The whole input file goes to RAM (because `fi.readlines()` works this way) and also `processed_lines` takes much memory too. In other words, your script consumes too much memory and it would be inefficient in case of really huge `input.txt` (100 million lines, for instance). Is it possible to upgrade your script to solve this issue?

Comment: @Fomalhaut I updated my answer, please take a loop :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `line = next(fi)` is not processed correctly under different `Process`.

It's possible to bypass the need of using `next(fi)` with the help of temporary buffer of lines filled by the main thread of program and read by each process. For this role it's better to use `multiprocessing.Queue`.

So this is my script:

```
from time import sleep, time
import multiprocessing as mp
import queue


MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 1000
QUEUE_TIMEOUT = 0.000001
POOL_NUMBER = 4


def handle(line):
    sleep(0.00001)  # Some processing here that takes time
    return line.strip()[::-1]


def target(fout, write_lock, lines_queue):
    while True:
        try:
            line = lines_queue.get(timeout=1.0)
            line = handle(line)
            with write_lock:
                print(line, file=fout)
                fout.flush()
        except queue.Empty:
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    time_begin = time()

    with open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
        write_lock = mp.Lock()
        lines_queue = mp.Queue()

        processes = [
            mp.Process(target=target, args=(fout, write_lock, lines_queue))
            for _ in range(POOL_NUMBER)
        ]
        for p in processes:
            p.start()

        with open('input.txt', 'r') as fin:
            while True:
                try:
                    while lines_queue.qsize() < MAX_QUEUE_SIZE:
                        line = next(fin)
                        lines_queue.put(line)
                    sleep(QUEUE_TIMEOUT)
                except StopIteration:
                    break

        for p in processes:
            p.join()

    time_end = time()
    print("Time:", time_end - time_begin)
```

On my CPU I got this result:

```
POOL_NUMBER = 1 -> Time: 17.877086400985718
POOL_NUMBER = 2 -> Time: 8.611438989639282
POOL_NUMBER = 3 -> Time: 6.332395553588867
POOL_NUMBER = 4 -> Time: 5.321753978729248
```