# EOF error in multiprocessing while using dictionary type?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have this following piece of code that does exactly what I want it to. However for files with file size of higher magnitude, it breaks and gives me an error:

ERROR: "raise EOFError"

```
def co(operation, in_queue, processed_lines):
    while True:
        item = in_queue.get()
        line_number, line = item

        if line is None:
            return

        line = line + operation + "changed"
        processed_lines[line_number] = line

def _fo(file_name, operation):

    manager = Manager()
    results = manager.dict()
    work = manager.Queue(10)

    pool = []
    for i in range(10):
        p = Process(target=co, args=(operation, work, results))
        p.start()
        pool.append(p)

    with open(file_name) as f:
        num_lines = 0
        iters = itertools.chain(f, (None,) * 10)
        for num_and_line in enumerate(iters):
            work.put(num_and_line)
                num_lines += 1

    for p in pool:
        p.join()

    return [results[idx] for idx in range(num_lines - 10)]
```

Now I am aware that my main process is closing before my multi process could write back to results however I am unable to resolve it. I am already gracefully closing my process using p.join(). I tried putting p.close() before p.join() but then it gives me error: "'Process' object has no attribute 'close'".

What is that I can do to resolve this here please ?

Error:

```
2020-10-01T15:55:22.488-05:00   item = in_queue.get()

2020-10-01T15:55:22.488-05:00   File "<string>", line 2, in get

2020-10-01T15:55:22.488-05:00   File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 757, in _callmethod

2020-10-01T15:55:22.488-05:00   kind, result = conn.recv()

2020-10-01T15:55:22.488-05:00   File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 250, in recv

2020-10-01T15:55:22.488-05:00   buf = self._recv_bytes()

2020-10-01T15:55:22.488-05:00   File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 407, in _recv_bytes

2020-10-01T15:55:22.488-05:00   buf = self._recv(4)

2020-10-01T15:55:22.488-05:00   File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 383, in _recv

2020-10-01T15:55:22.488-05:00   raise EOFError

2020-10-01T15:55:22.488-05:00   EOFError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I am aware that my main process is closing before my multi process
> could write back to results however I am unable to resolve it.

So this doesn't seem like it is a matter of the size of the input file, but rather something larger to process that is just taking more time and your willingness to terminate the main program early? Or for some reason you are choosing to exit your main process before processing has finished. It sounds like you need an extra form of proper cancellation to stop the workers before you move on and exit.

> I am already gracefully closing my process using p.join().

`Process.join()` is not really a graceful close of your main process. It just implies that the particular scope is blocking until your list of worker processes choose to terminate. If for any reason you kill your app with a `KeyboardInterrupt` or tell your main thread to exit while this is running in another thread, your main will terminate and your child processes will hit an EOF when trying to read from the parent process for more work items.

The implementing of the main and the child processes is set up in a way where all of the workers will be sent `None` values on the queue to signal for them to exit, which then unblocks all of the `Process.join()` calls in the main. If you do not send a `None` to each worker before that point and you exit your main, you can encounter the EOF problem because the workers have not been stopped.

> I tried putting p.close() before p.join() but then it gives me error: "'Process' object has no attribute 'close'".

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.close
"New in version 3.7."

That implies you are running a python version less than 3.7. But you could call `terminate` or `kill` instead, if your main process is going to exit early. It would be best to stop sending lines to your workers, and send the final `None` values to get the workers to stop gracefully, and then use the `join()` calls to wait on them.

```
with open(file_name) as f:
    num_lines = 0
    iters = itertools.chain(f, (None,) * 10)
    for num_and_line in enumerate(iters):
        work.put(num_and_line)
            num_lines += 1
```

This block of code iterates on every line, sending it to the queue, and finally sends a `None` value for each of the workers (10 in this case). If you decide you want to cancel the work then you need to stop sending lines and instead send 10 `None` values, and break.

For anything more details than this, you would need to describe your cancellation circumstances.

Comment: If I was to use a dictionary instead of a list for my results, will, sending a None from function co upon encountering a blank line, still be graceful a graceful way to close ?

Comment: The collection of the results happens after your worker receives a value from the queue and decides to return if it sees a `None`. So the choice of how you want to store the results are not related to the queue and the graceful exit. On a side note however, the choice to use a dict just for the goal of having sorted lines is not reliable. Python dict makes no guarantee that the keys are sorted. It only happens to be a lucky implementation detail of the CPython dict that your integer keys end up appearing sorted. A list will actually maintain sort order via the index being the line number.