# Is there a common Java utility to break a list into batches?

Tags: java, collections

I wrote myself a utility to break a list into batches of given size. I just wanted to know if there is already any apache commons util for this.

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> getBatches(List<T> collection,int batchSize){
    int i = 0;
    List<List<T>> batches = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
    while(i<collection.size()){
        int nextInc = Math.min(collection.size()-i,batchSize);
        List<T> batch = collection.subList(i,i+nextInc);
        batches.add(batch);
        i = i + nextInc;
    }

    return batches;
}
```

Please let me know if there any existing utility already for the same.

Comment: Not sure this is off-topic.  The question is not "what library does this" but "how can I do this with apache common utils".

Comment: @FlorianF I agree with you. This question and its answers are very useful, and it could be well saved with a small edit. It was a lazy action to close it hastily.

Comment: Found useful blog post with nice class and benchmarks here : https://e.printstacktrace.blog/divide-a-list-to-lists-of-n-size-in-Java-8/

Answer (score 370, accepted):

Check out   [`Lists.partition(java.util.List, int)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition(java.util.List,%20int)) from [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

> Returns consecutive sublists of a list, each of the same size (the final list may be smaller). For example, partitioning a list containing `[a, b, c, d, e]` with a partition size of 3 yields `[[a, b, c]`, `[d, e]]` -- an outer list containing two inner lists of three and two elements, all in the original order.

Comment: [link](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#partition%28java.lang.Iterable,%20int%29) `partition documentation` and 
[link](http://www.baeldung.com/java-list-split) `code example`

Comment: For apache common users, the function is also available: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#partition(java.util.List,%20int)

Comment: f you are working with a list I use the "Apache Commons Collections 4" library. It has a partition method in the ListUtils class:

...
int targetSize = 100;
List<Integer> largeList = ...
List<List<Integer>> output = ListUtils.partition(largeList, targetSize);
This method is adapted from http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe how hard this is to do in Java.

Comment: Checked both of these methods with the benchmark (via Guava and via AtomicInteger + groupingBy)

Unexpected, but Guava`s way is the winner (up to 8 times faster)

Answer (score 125):

In case you want to produce a Java-8 stream of batches, you can try the following code:

```
public static <T> Stream<List<T>> batches(List<T> source, int length) {
    if (length <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("length = " + length);
    int size = source.size();
    if (size <= 0)
        return Stream.empty();
    int fullChunks = (size - 1) / length;
    return IntStream.range(0, fullChunks + 1).mapToObj(
        n -> source.subList(n * length, n == fullChunks ? size : (n + 1) * length));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14);

    System.out.println("By 3:");
    batches(list, 3).forEach(System.out::println);
    
    System.out.println("By 4:");
    batches(list, 4).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
By 3:
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12]
[13, 14]
By 4:
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
[13, 14]
```

Comment: How do I break, continue or return in this approach?

Comment: @Tyr1on In `main(String[])`, instead of `Stream.forEach(Consumer)` you use `Stream.iterator()` and make a basic `for` loop.

Comment: How can one apply this approach on the infinite stream? Like this one: Stream.generate(Math.random).

Answer (score 42):

Use Apache Commons [ListUtils.partition](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#partition-java.util.List-int-).

```
org.apache.commons.collections4.ListUtils.partition(final List<T> list, final int size)
```

Answer (score 33):

Here is a simple solution for Java 8+:

```java
public static <T> Collection<List<T>> prepareChunks(List<T> inputList, int chunkSize) {
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    return inputList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / chunkSize)).values();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the documentation discourage using side effect operations in streams?

Answer (score 26):

With Java 9 you can use [`IntStream.iterate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate-int-java.util.function.IntPredicate-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) with `hasNext` condition. So you can simplify the code of your method to this:

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> getBatches(List<T> collection, int batchSize) {
    return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < collection.size(), i -> i + batchSize)
            .mapToObj(i -> collection.subList(i, Math.min(i + batchSize, collection.size())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Using `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`, the result of `getBatches(numbers, 4)` will be:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 23):

Another approach is to use `Collectors.groupingBy` of indices and then map the grouped indices to the actual elements:

```
    final List<Integer> numbers = range(1, 12)
            .boxed()
            .collect(toList());
    System.out.println(numbers);

    final List<List<Integer>> groups = range(0, numbers.size())
            .boxed()
            .collect(groupingBy(index -> index / 4))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .map(indices -> indices
                    .stream()
                    .map(numbers::get)
                    .collect(toList()))
            .collect(toList());
    System.out.println(groups);
```

Output:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>
> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]

Comment: @Sebien This does work for the general case. The `groupingBy` is done on the elements of the `IntStream.range`, not the list elements. See e.g. https://ideone.com/KYBc7h.

Comment: what's range() function?

Comment: I used the range function from here : import static java.util.stream.IntStream.range;

Comment: Generics based solution based on this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77929672/337666

Answer (score 11):

I came up with this one:

```
private static <T> List<List<T>> partition(Collection<T> members, int maxSize)
{
    List<List<T>> res = new ArrayList<>();

    List<T> internal = new ArrayList<>();

    for (T member : members)
    {
        internal.add(member);

        if (internal.size() == maxSize)
        {
            res.add(internal);
            internal = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
    if (internal.isEmpty() == false)
    {
        res.add(internal);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, you also can simplify `internal.isEmpty() == false` to `!internal.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 9):

Here an example:

```
final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
final int partitionSize=3;
final List<Object> list=new ArrayList<>();
            list.add("A");
            list.add("B");
            list.add("C");
            list.add("D");
            list.add("E");
       
        
final Collection<List<Object>> subLists=list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy
                (it->counter.getAndIncrement() / partitionSize))
                .values();
        System.out.println(subLists);
```

**Input:**
[A, B, C, D, E]

**Output:**
[[A, B, C], [D, E]]

You can find examples here:
https://e.printstacktrace.blog/divide-a-list-to-lists-of-n-size-in-Java-8/

Answer (score 7):

The following example demonstrates chunking of a List:

```
package de.thomasdarimont.labs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class SplitIntoChunks {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11);

        List<List<Integer>> chunks = chunk(ints, 4);

        System.out.printf("Ints:   %s%n", ints);
        System.out.printf("Chunks: %s%n", chunks);
    }

    public static <T> List<List<T>> chunk(List<T> input, int chunkSize) {

        int inputSize = input.size();
        int chunkCount = (int) Math.ceil(inputSize / (double) chunkSize);

        Map<Integer, List<T>> map = new HashMap<>(chunkCount);
        List<List<T>> chunks = new ArrayList<>(chunkCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < inputSize; i++) {

            map.computeIfAbsent(i / chunkSize, (ignore) -> {

                List<T> chunk = new ArrayList<>();
                chunks.add(chunk);
                return chunk;

            }).add(input.get(i));
        }

        return chunks;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Ints:   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
Chunks: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
```

Answer (score 5):

There was [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265999/java-splitting-list-of-strings-into-smaller-list) that was closed as being a duplicate of this one, but if you read it closely, it's subtly different. So in case someone (like me) actually wants to split a list into *a given number of almost equally sized sublists*, then read on.

I simply ported the algorithm described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130016/splitting-a-list-into-n-parts-of-approximately-equal-length/37414115#37414115) to Java.

```
@Test
public void shouldPartitionListIntoAlmostEquallySizedSublists() {

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g");
    int numberOfPartitions = 3;

    List<List<String>> split = IntStream.range(0, numberOfPartitions).boxed()
            .map(i -> list.subList(
                    partitionOffset(list.size(), numberOfPartitions, i),
                    partitionOffset(list.size(), numberOfPartitions, i + 1)))
            .collect(toList());

    assertThat(split, hasSize(numberOfPartitions));
    assertEquals(list.size(), split.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).count());
    assertThat(split, hasItems(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"), Arrays.asList("d", "e"), Arrays.asList("f", "g")));
}

private static int partitionOffset(int length, int numberOfPartitions, int partitionIndex) {
    return partitionIndex * (length / numberOfPartitions) + Math.min(partitionIndex, length % numberOfPartitions);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Similar to OP without streams and libs, but conciser:

```
public <T> List<List<T>> getBatches(List<T> collection, int batchSize) {
    List<List<T>> batches = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < collection.size(); i += batchSize) {
        batches.add(collection.subList(i, Math.min(i + batchSize, collection.size())));
    }
    return batches;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using various cheats from the web, I came to this solution:

```
int[] count = new int[1];
final int CHUNK_SIZE = 500;
Map<Integer, List<Long>> chunkedUsers = users.stream().collect( Collectors.groupingBy( 
    user -> {
        count[0]++;
        return Math.floorDiv( count[0], CHUNK_SIZE );
    } )
);
```

We use count to mimic a normal collection index.
Then, we group the collection elements in buckets, using the algebraic quotient as bucket number.
The final map contains as **key** the bucket number, as **value** the bucket itself.

You can then easily do an operation on each of the buckets with:

```
chunkedUsers.values().forEach( ... );
```

Comment: Could use an `AtomicInteger` for count.

Answer (score 4):

You can use below code to get the batch of list.

```
Iterable<List<T>> batchIds = Iterables.partition(list, batchSize);
```

You need to import Google Guava library to use above code.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `List#subList()` returns a view of the underlying collection, which can result in unexpected consequences when editing the smaller lists - the edits will reflect in the original collection or may throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using vanilla java and the super secret modulo operator :)

Given the content/order of the chunks doesn't matter, this would be the easiest approach. (When preparing stuff for multi-threading it usually doesn't matter, which elements are processed on which thread for example, just need an equal distribution).

```
public static <T> List<T>[] chunk(List<T> input, int chunkCount) {
    List<T>[] chunks = new List[chunkCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < chunkCount; i++) {
        chunks[i] = new LinkedList<T>();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
        chunks[i % chunkCount].add(input.get(i));
    }

    return chunks;
}
```

Usage:

```
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j");

    List<String>[] chunks = chunk(list, 4);

    for (List<String> chunk : chunks) {
        System.out.println(chunk);
    }
```

Output:

```
[a, e, i]
[b, f, j]
[c, g]
[d, h]
```

Answer (score 2):

if someone is looking for Kotlin version, here is

```
list.chunked(size)
```

or

```
list.windowed(size)
```

once had an interview question and I wrote below one =D

```
fun <T> batch(list: List<T>, limit: Int): List<List<T>> {
    val result = ArrayList<List<T>>()

    var batch = ArrayList<T>()

    for (i in list) {
        batch.add(i)
        if (batch.size == limit) {
            result.add(batch)
            batch = ArrayList()
        }
    }
    if (batch.isNotEmpty()) {
        result.add(batch)
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for the `chunked`.

Comment: Pointing out that `chunked/windowed` is  not lazy and isn't backed up by the original list (Compared to `Lists.partition`). It will immediately create a new list with all the many inner lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<T> batch = collection.subList(i,i+nextInc);
->
List<T> batch = collection.subList(i, i = i + nextInc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below solution using Java 8 Streams:

```
        //Sample Input
        List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
        IntStream.range(1,999).forEach((num) -> {
            input.add(""+num);
        });
        
        //Identify no. of batches
        int BATCH_SIZE = 10;
        int multiples = input.size() /  BATCH_SIZE;
        if(input.size()%BATCH_SIZE!=0) {
            multiples = multiples + 1;
        }
        
        //Process each batch
        IntStream.range(0, multiples).forEach((indx)->{
            List<String> batch = input.stream().skip(indx * BATCH_SIZE).limit(BATCH_SIZE).collect(Collectors.toList());
            System.out.println("Batch Items:"+batch);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to solve this, question:

```
public class CollectionUtils {

    /**
    * Splits the collection into lists with given batch size
    * @param collection to split in to batches
    * @param batchsize size of the batch
    * @param <T> it maintains the input type to output type
    * @return nested list
    */
    public static <T> List<List<T>> makeBatch(Collection<T> collection, int batchsize) {

        List<List<T>> totalArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<T> tempItems = new ArrayList<>();

        Iterator<T> iterator = collection.iterator();

        for (int i = 0; i < collection.size(); i++) {
            tempItems.add(iterator.next());
            if ((i+1) % batchsize == 0) {
                totalArrayList.add(tempItems);
                tempItems = new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }

        if (tempItems.size() > 0) {
            totalArrayList.add(tempItems);
        }

        return totalArrayList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner in Java 8 would be:

```
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

private static <T> Collection<List<T>> partition(List<T> xs, int size) {
    return IntStream.range(0, xs.size())
            .boxed()
            .collect(collectingAndThen(toMap(identity(), xs::get), Map::entrySet))
            .stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(x -> x.getKey() / size, mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())))
            .values();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with generics based on answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41500804/337666Adrean

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.IntStream.range;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CollectionUtils {

    public static <T> List<List<T>> partition(Collection<T> input, int size) {

        if (size <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid batch size of: " + size + ". Size should be greater than zero");
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") T[] inputArray = (T[]) input.toArray();
        return range(0, input.size())
                .boxed()
                .collect(groupingBy(index -> index / size))
                .values()
                .stream()
                .map(indices -> indices
                        .stream()
                        .map(x -> inputArray[x])
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`import com.google.common.collect.Lists;`

`List<List<T>> batches = Lists.partition(List<T>,batchSize)`

Use Lists.partition(List,batchSize). You need to import `Lists` from google common package (`com.google.common.collect.Lists`)

It will return List of `List<T>` with and the size of every element equal to your `batchSize`.

Comment: You can also use their own `subList(startIndex, endIndex)` method for breaking list based on required index.