# Spring JPA deleteInBatch causes StackOverflow

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have a question to deleting Items from db using deleteInBatch. 
I have an object A having a list of Objects B like:

```
class A {
private List <B>;
}
```

The list contains more than 7k elements. 
So now I have to remove A and all its elements. I tried via deleteInBatch but I get

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed;
nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Deleting the items with a sipmle delete method works but it takes more than 5 minutes. 
My delete code is:

```
public void delete(Long id) {
A a = repository.findOne(id);
deleteElements(a);
repository.delete(a);
}

private void deleteElements(A a) {
repository.deleteInBatch(a.getListOfB);
}
```

Is there a good solution to speed up the deleting process or how to change so that deleteinbatch does not take all hibernate stack - without increasing it?

The complete Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1259)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:163)
net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:206)
net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:179)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
```

And so on...

```
root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SqlNode.<init>(SqlNode.java:34)
sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor36.newInstance(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.SqlASTFactory.create(SqlASTFactory.java:256)
antlr.ASTFactory.create(ASTFactory.java:153)
antlr.ASTFactory.create(ASTFactory.java:186)
org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2018)
org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2026)
org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2026)
```

And so on....

Comment: could you post the complete stacktrace?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in your case, the delete query will be translated by `JpaRepository` to be looks like this.

```
delete from [table_name] where [criteria] = id or [criteria] = id (and so on...)
```

the jvm throws a stack overflow error because the `HqlSqlBaseWalker` is trying to search all the *or* (or basically the `where` criteria) statement

I guess, in your case, you could try to generate your own delete query and then execute it or you could try to split the data into few lists.

Comment: So, you mean that "batch" doesn't really create a JDBC batch statement internally? That's rather bad news for any DBA who's tuning cursor caches...

Comment: @LukasEder well, I think the problem lies on the "batch" term itself in here.  I mean, what we usually expect on this case is that hibernate will split the data and try to insert those data like once query for every 100 of data. but, if you read at the api doc, it does mention that the function will indeed create a single `query`. so, i think the lesson in here is we should think twice to name our public api ;)

Comment: Yes, I created my own delete query. The process took 3 min, but I created an index on the key and it works good. Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up combining `deleteInBatch` with [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026885/is-there-a-common-java-utility-to-break-a-list-into-batches):

```java
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
...
Lists.partition(messages, 500)
        .forEach(fragmentMessageDao::deleteInBatch);
```

For me, this gave a proper and elegant solution because I already needed the data for another calculation

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue (java.lang.StackOverflowError) and created a method with my own delete query, e.g. deleteByIdAndYear(...), to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case deleting entities in smaller chunks helped. 
Chunks of 100 items worked just fine.