# how to split a list into a given number of sub-lists?

Tags: java, string, list, guava, apache-commons

I have a list that may be over `1000` strings, however I do not know how many exactly.

What is the best way to split this `list` into *smaller lists* without loosing any members of the list?

For example If I have a list of `1323` members, how can I best split it into 3 almost evenly sized lists?

I have seen the `Guava` and `Commons` way of splitting lists by the partition function, but that function will split the list into given size of chunks and not given number of groups (sub-lists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-) has a function `Lists.partition` which will do this for you

Usage:

```
Lists.partition(mylist, mylist.size()/3);
```

Comment: thanks , but I need to know many lists it will produce?

Comment: thank you, so this will break the list into 3 smaller lists as evenly as it can?

Comment: This will not work :( in case you want 2 groups and the size of your list is 3, then the result will be 3 groups (because 3/2=1).