# How to split a string every N words

Tags: java

I want to split one big string into smaller parts, so given for example:

```
"A B C D E F G H I J K L"
```

I want to get array (String []): `[A,B,C,D], [E,F,G,H], [I,J,K,L]`

Is there any regex for that or I need to do that manually so first to split every space and then concat every N words. ??

Comment: First you still need to do `split(" ")`. After that you can chunk the results with any method described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026885/is-there-a-common-java-utility-to-break-a-list-into-batches

Comment: @Lino I wrote - I want to get an array.

Comment: @Lino String[], sorry.

Comment: `split(" ")` would create too many unneccessary strings tho

Comment: @AdityaArora do you have other idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a string at every n-th character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297347/splitting-a-string-at-every-n-th-character)

Comment: @AdityaArora No. I want to split every stirng not character.... It's just example in question.

Comment: are your words always only 1 character?

Comment: @warch no, they are multiple characters.

Comment: then my solution should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a regex that describes this pattern.
e.g. `"((?:\w+\s*){4})"`

[image]

Or in simple words:

- The `\w+\s*` part means that there are 1 or multiple word-characters (e.g. text, digits) followed by 0, 1 or multiple whitespace characters.
- It is surrounded in braces and followed by `{4}` to indicate that we want this to occur 4 times.
- Finally that again is wrapped in braces, because we want to capture that result.
- By contrast the braces which were used to specify `{4}` are preceded by a `(?: ...)` prefix, which makes it a "non-capturing-group". We don't want to capture the individual matches just yet.

You can use that pattern in java to extract each chunk of 4 occurrences.

[image]

And than next, you can simply split each individual result with a second regex, `\s+` ( = whitespace)

## Edit

One more thing, you may notice that the first matched group also contains whitespace at the end. You can get rid of that with a more advanced regex: `((?:\w+\s+){3}(?:\w+))\s*`

[image]

Comment: your regex looks cleaner than mine but your regex does not match the last group. but i don't know why.

Comment: @warch thank you for pointing that out. Should be fixed now. It's the `\s+` which matches 1 or more spaces,  while `\s*` matches 0,1 or more spaces.  Because the last match may not have a space at the end, the 2nd is needed.

Comment: Can you link the website where you got the explanation?

Comment: @CyberAvater I used https://regex101.com/ , then took some screenshots and added some text to them.

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex for this:

e.g.:

```
    String x = "AAS BASD CAFAS DAFASF EASFASF FAFSASF GA HASF IAS JAS KAS LSA";
    ArrayList<String> found = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+\\s\\w+\\s\\w+)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(x);
    while (m.find()) {
        String s = m.group();
        found.add(s);
    }

    //if you want to convert your List to an Array
    String[] result = found.toArray(new String[0]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Result: `[AAS BASD CAFAS DAFASF, EASFASF FAFSASF GA HASF, IAS JAS KAS LSA]`

This pattern (`"(\\w+\\s\\w+\\s\\w+\\s\\w+)"`) matches 4 words separated by one space. The loop iterates over every found match and adds it to your result list.

Comment: With `String[] z = a.split("(?:\\w+\\s\\w+\\s\\w+)") ;` I get only third word in list, all others are blank.

Comment: you should not use split, use group instead.

Comment: and you have to iterate over the matches

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this,

for ex. let your string be

```java
String str = "A B C D E F G H I J K L";
```

one way to split it would be using regular expression

```java
 java.util.Arrays.toString(str.split("(?<=\\G....)"))
```

here the `....` represent how many characters in each string, another way to specify the pattern would be `.{4}`

another way would be

```java
Iterable<String> strArr = Splitter.fixedLength(3).split(str );
```

there could be more ways to achieve the same

Comment: What is `Splitter`?

Comment: it's a google library  check here https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html

Comment: It won't work. I want to split every word not every character. So your answer is wrong.

Comment: this would only work for the example given (1 character words) and only 3 groups my solution works for words of arbitrary lenght and arbitrary number of words

Comment: You're mostly correct. Just change your `....` with the check of words: `java.util.Arrays.toString(str.split("(?<=\\G\\s?\\w{1,10}\\s\\w{1,10}\\s\\w{1,10}\\s\\w{1,10})"))` Note that `\\w{1,10}` is mandatory rather than `\\w+` because of how Java is implemented (the latter will produce an error). You can use `\\w{1,100}`, if you want. Just don't use `\\w+`.