# Binning python tuples. Error due to empty bins

Tags: python, list, numpy, binning

I have a problem sorting list items to bins. I have two lists, X and Y, with  corresponding X and Y values (which could also be one list of tuples, obviously). Next, I need to split the X range in 10 equal bins and sort the X values and corresponding Y values to those bins, so that I know what Y values belong to which X bin (i.e. into which bin falls the X value of each Y value), and then take the median of all Y values in each bin. This gives me ten bin-median pairs. This is working fine in principle with the following code in which I also calculate the X-center of each bin.

```
    bins = np.linspace(max(X), min(X), 10)
    digitized = np.digitize(X, bins)
    bin_centers = []
    for j in range(len(bins) - 1):
        bin_centers.append((bins[j] + bins[j + 1]) / 2.)
    bin_means = [np.median(np.asarray(Y)[digitized == j])
                 for j in range(1, len(bins))]
```

The problem now is that sometimes a bin is empty since there is no X-value in this bin. In this case the line

```
    bin_means = [np.median(np.asarray(Y)[digitized == j])
                 for j in range(1, len(bins))]
```

raises the error

```
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:55: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

because of the empty bin. How can I fix that? I also tried `right=True/False` in `numpy.digitize` with no luck. I think it would be best to delete the entries in the three lists `bin_centers`, in `digitized`, and `bins` before doing this list comprehension that calculates the median values. But I'm not sure how to do that, how to find out which bins are empty and then what has to be deleted from those lists and how.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What is going on here? What are `X` and `Y` holding? In what sense to values in `X` correspond with those in `Y`?

Comment: What numbers they contain is basically arbitrary, as long as every number x belongs to a value y, so there are pairs (x1, y1), (x2, y2), and so on. In my case, X contains magnitudes and Y contains magnitude deviations for each x value. Plotting that gives an X/Y scatter plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Scipy, you could call [scipy.stats.binned_statistic](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html):

```
import scipy.stats as stats
statistic, bin_edges, binnumber = stats.binned_statistic(
    x=X, values=Y, statistic='median', bins=bins)
statistic = statistic[np.isfinite(statistic)]
print(statistic)
```

yields

```
[ 15.  90.  50.  55.  40.  60.]
```

---

Without SciPy, I think you would need a list comprehension.
As you suggested, you could avoid the RuntimeWarning by filtering out those bins which are empty. You can do that with an `if-condition` inside a list comprehension:

```
masks = [(digitized == j) for j in range(1, len(bins))]
bin_medians = [np.median(Y[mask]) for mask in masks if mask.any()]
```

Also note that the error message you are seeing is a warning, not an Exception. You could (alternatively) suppress the error message with

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", 'Mean of empty slice.')
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", 'invalid value encountered in double_scalar')
```

---

There is a way to compute the bin_centers more quickly:

```
bin_centers = []
for j in range(len(bins) - 1):
    bin_centers.append((bins[j] + bins[j + 1]) / 2.)
```

could be simplified to

```
bin_centers = bins[:-1] + (bins[1]-bins[0])/2
```

---

So, for example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", 'Mean of empty slice.')
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", 'invalid value encountered in double_scalar')

np.random.seed(123)

X = np.random.random(10)
bins = np.linspace(min(X), max(X), 10)
digitized = np.digitize(X, bins)-1
bin_centers = bins + (bins[1]-bins[0])/2

Y = range(0, 100, 10)
Y = np.asarray(Y, dtype='float')
bin_medians = [np.median(Y[digitized == j]) for j in range(len(bins))]
print(bin_medians)

plt.scatter(bin_centers, bin_medians)
plt.show()
```

yields

```
[15.0, 90.0, 50.0, 55.0, nan, 40.0, nan, nan, nan, 60.0]
```

[image]

If your purpose is only to make the scatter plot, then it is not necessary to remove the nans since `matplotlib` will ignore them anyway.

If you really want to remove the nans, then you could use

```
no_nans = np.isfinite(bin_medians)
bin_medians = bin_medians[no_nans]
bin_centers = bin_centers[no_nans]
```

---

In the above, I opted for using `warnings.filterwarnings` to just suppress the warnings. If you don't wish to suppress warnings, and would rather filter the nans from `bin_medians` and from the corresponding locations from `bin_centers`, then:

```
bin_centers = bins + (bins[1]-bins[0])/2
masks = [(digitized == j) for j in range(len(bins))]
bin_centers, bin_medians = zip(*[(center, np.median(Y[mask]))
                                 for center, mask in zip(bin_centers, masks)
                                 if mask.any()])
```

Comment: Thank you, this might be what I am looking for! Two questions about that: I also need to get rid of the bin_center entries that correspond to the empty bins, because I need to plot scatter(bin_centers, bin_medians). Is there a better way to kick them out than to get the indices where `mask.any()` is `False` in a for-loop (`for i in range(len(masks)): if not mask.any(): del_index.append(i)` and then `bin_centers = [m for n, m in enumerate(bin_centers) if n not in del_index]`? And also, why is there six elements in your list with scipy and only five with numpy? I don't get the difference.

Comment: I'm aware that it would have to be `if not masks[i].any()`, sorry ;)

Comment: or rather any(masks[i]) since it's not a numpy array

Comment: If your ultimate purpose is the make a scatter plot with matplotlib, then it is not necessary to remove the nans. `plt.scatter` will simply ignore them.

Comment: Regarding the second question: "why does `binned_statistic` show 6 medians": `bins` represents the bin *edges*. `min(X)` and `max(X)` fall right on bin edges. `np.digitize` places `min(X)` in bin 1, and `max(X)` in bin 10. Since `min(X)` is the smallest value of `X` nothing ever falls in bin 0, and the one value in bin 10, `max(X)` gets ignored when you loop over `range(1, len(bins))`. So it is an "off-by-one" error. I'll post some code showing one way to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the question, but here's something to maybe get you started:

```
In [3]: X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

In [4]: Y = [chr(96+x) for x in X]

In [8]: Z = zip(X, Y)    # Create a pairing - this can be done after a sort if they're not in whatever 'order' you want for your correspondence

In [9]: Z
Out[9]:
[(1, 'a'),
 (2, 'b'),
 (3, 'c'),
 (4, 'd'),
 (5, 'e'),
 (6, 'f'),
 (7, 'g'),
 (8, 'h'),
 (9, 'i'),
 (10, 'j')]
```

At this point you can do something like `sorted(Z, key=lambda el: -ord(el[1]))` or whatever to sort based on your criteria. Obviously it'd be more meaningful than the example.

Finally, to chunk into equal-length parts, which I think you might also want, take a look at the [wide variety of possibilities given as answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130016/splitting-a-list-of-arbitrary-size-into-only-roughly-n-equal-parts).

If that's not what you were looking for, apologies.