# Divide a list into 3 parts in python

Tags: python, list

I am looking to divide a list into 3 parts in python. If the list doesn't divide by 3, I would like it to 'fill' the first column then the second, then the third.

e.g:

```
1|2|3

1|3|
2|


1|3|
2|4|

1|3|5
2|4|

1|3|5
2|4|6
```

And so on.

I am currently doing something like this, which doesn't give the desired results. Have also played around with using `%` to no avail

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
a = [:l/3]
b = [l/3:(l/3)*2 ]
c = [(l/3)*2 :]
```

All help appreciated, thanks

**Note** The answer to [Splitting a list of into N parts of approximately equal length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130016/splitting-a-list-of-arbitrary-size-into-only-roughly-n-equal-parts) gives the opposite result, so please don't mark this question as already answered

Comment: I didn't get you. Say the list is `[1,2,3,4,5]`. What o/p do you want?

Comment: What does "fill" mean? What does "doesn't give the desired results" mean? What does `1|2|3` mean? Is that a list? Does it relate with `[1,2,3,4,5]` of the second example in anyway?

Answer (score 2):

There is a recipe in [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) that will do this:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

You could use this as-is or modify for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I just drew up.

```
import math
startArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
secLength = math.ceil(len(startArray) / 3)
newArray = []
newArray.append(startArray[:secLength])
newArray.append(startArray[secLength : 2*secLength])
newArray.append(startArray[2*secLength:]);
print(newArray)
```

For this example, the return is `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

If your array is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, it returns `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7]]`

Comment: When I ran this (after adding an integer cast to the slices) my results were [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]

Comment: Where are you integer casting? Where I use math.ceil?

Comment: math.ceil() returns an integer, therefore the integer cast does not matter

Answer (score 0):

Continued to try work this out, got this:

```
import math
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

col = 3
height = int(math.ceil(len(l)/col))

print height
a = l[:height+1]
b = l[height+1:(height+1)*2]
c = l[(height+1)*2:]

print l
print a
print b
print c
```

Comment: That is practically the same exact thing that I already posted...

Comment: And it doesn't work? This printed this for me:`[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7]
[]`

Comment: I figured out what the confusion between our codes are. Yours works 100% in Python 2, mine works 100% in Python 3. Must be different behaviors somewhere

Comment: in python 2 ceil seems to return a float. but even when i cast it, I don't get the same result as you, strange