# Split a string into N equal parts?

Tags: python

I have a string I would like to split into N equal parts.

For example, imagine I had a string with length 128 and I want to split it in to 4 chunks of length 32 each; i.e., first 32 chars, then the second 32 and so on.

How can I do this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
import textwrap
print(textwrap.wrap("123456789", 2))
#prints ['12', '34', '56', '78', '9']
```

Note: be careful with whitespace etc - this may or may not be what you want.

```
"""Wrap a single paragraph of text, returning a list of wrapped lines.

    Reformat the single paragraph in 'text' so it fits in lines of no
    more than 'width' columns, and return a list of wrapped lines.  By
    default, tabs in 'text' are expanded with string.expandtabs(), and
    all other whitespace characters (including newline) are converted to
    space.  See TextWrapper class for available keyword args to customize
    wrapping behaviour.
    """
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3, you enclose the `print` in parentheses.

Comment: Are you aware that there are people programming in languages that are probably older than you? Even older than Python 2! (SCNR)

Answer (score 72):

You may use a simple loop:

```
parts = [your_string[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(your_string), n)]
```

Answer (score 36):

Another common way of grouping elements into n-length groups:

```
>>> s = '1234567890'
>>> list(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(s)]*2)))
['12', '34', '56', '78', '90']
```

This method comes straight from the docs for [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: This is much better than mine! Mind if I steal this for future use? :)

Comment: Note that _"The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence"_ so if the data series cannot fit into equal groups of n-length any extra will be left off.

Comment: That `list` call looks redundant; why did you add it?

Comment: @Air The 'map' function returns a list in python 2 and a generator object in python 3, which would still work. However, I thought a list would make for a better output for the purposes of this answer.

Comment: Perfect!, converting from `ip6.arpa.` string using `':'.join(map(''.join, zip(*[reversed(qn.split('.'))]*4)))`

Answer (score 7):

Recursive way:

```
def split_str(seq, chunk, skip_tail=False):
    lst = []
    if chunk <= len(seq):
        lst.extend([seq[:chunk]])
        lst.extend(split_str(seq[chunk:], chunk, skip_tail))
    elif not skip_tail and seq:
        lst.extend([seq])
    return lst
```

Demo:

```
seq = "123456789abcdefghij"

print(split_str(seq, 3))
print(split_str(seq, 3, skip_tail=True))

# ['123', '456', '789', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'j']
# ['123', '456', '789', 'abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

Comment: What is the max length of the sequence? I'm receiving: "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" with ~25k chars.

Answer (score 6):

You can treat a string similarly to a list in many cases. There are lots of answers here: [Splitting a list of into N parts of approximately equal length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130016/splitting-a-list-of-arbitrary-size-into-only-roughly-n-equal-parts)

for example you could work out the `chunk_size = len(my_string)/N`

Then to access a chunk you can go `my_string[i: i + chunk_size]` (and then increment `i` by chunk_size) - either in a for loop or in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 6):

I like iterators!

```
def chunk(in_string,num_chunks):
    chunk_size = len(in_string)//num_chunks
    if len(in_string) % num_chunks: chunk_size += 1
    iterator = iter(in_string)
    for _ in range(num_chunks):
        accumulator = list()
        for _ in range(chunk_size):
            try: accumulator.append(next(iterator))
            except StopIteration: break
        yield ''.join(accumulator)

## DEMO
>>> string = "a"*32+"b"*32+"c"*32+"d"*32
>>> list(chunk(string,4))
['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 'cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc', 'dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd']
>>> string += "e" # so it's not evenly divisible
>>> list(chunk(string,4))
['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbcc', 'ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccddd', 'ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddde']
```

Also demonstrably faster than `textwrap.wrap`, although almost certainly less "good"

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: list(chunk(string,4)),number=500)
0.047726927170444355
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: textwrap.wrap(string,len(string)//4),number=500)
0.20812756575945457
```

And pretty easy to hack to work with any iterable (just drop the `str.join` and yield accumulator unless `isinstance(in_string,str)`)

```
# after a petty hack
>>> list(chunk([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],4))
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```