# How to reduce execution time while evaluating each item in a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, euclidean-distance

I have to build a distance matrix for locations

```
addresses = [(10.0, 20.0), (21.2318, 72.903), (26.4499, 80.3319), (20.0, 20.0), (19.114, 72.8927), (20.4189, 77.0153), (28.5377, 77.1217), (28.6201, 77.118), (28.5257, 77.2781)]
```

where distance in between two locations, is computed using the following function

```
def calculate_travel_distance(pointA,pointB):  
  return geodesic(pointA,pointB).meters
```

Distance Matrix is being build up using for loop as below

```
dist_matrix=[]
for pt1 in addresses:
  row_list =  [round(calculate_travel_distance(pt1,pt2),0) for pt2 in addresses]  
  dist_matrix.append(row_list)
```

When size of addresses grow up, it takes long time to execute i.e. 300 locations ( lat/lng pair) it takes 150 seconds to execute.
**Is it possible to bring down execution time to few secs(may be 10) for close to 400 locations. Please suggest.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of points `A` through `J`, then the matrix pairing all of those up looks like this:

```
AA AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ
BA BB BC BD BE BF BG BH BI BJ
CA CB CC CD CE CF CG CH CI CJ
DA DB DC DD DE DF DG DH DI DJ
EA EB EC ED EE EF EG EH EI EJ
FA FB FC FD FE FF FG FH FI FJ
GA GB GC GD GE GF GG GH GI GJ
HA HB HC HD HE HF HG HH HI HJ
IA IB IC ID IE IF IG IH II IJ
JA JB JC JD JE JF JG JH JI JJ
```

That's what your loop currently calculates. However, the distance `AB` and `BA` is equal, and the distances on the center line (`AA`, `BB`, ...) are always zero.

We can cut out workload in half (even less than half, from `n^2` to `n^2 / 2 - n`) by calculating only the distances between points where `x < y` in the matrix.

```
   AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ
      BC BD BE BF BG BH BI BJ
         CD CE CF CG CH CI CJ
            DE DF DG DH DI DJ
               EF EG EH EI EJ
                  FG FH FI FJ
                     GH GI GJ
                        HI HJ
                           IJ
```

The blanks can be filled easily by mirroring the upper triangle. Staying within the example, this:

```
addresses = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']

distances = []

for x, a in enumerate(addresses):
    row = []
    distances.append(row)
    for y, b in enumerate(addresses):
        if x < y:
            row.append(a + b)               # actually calculate something
        elif x == y:
            row.append('--')                # that's always 0
        else:
            row.append(distances[y][x])     # we already calculated that

for row in distances:
    print(' '.join(row))
```

gives us this:

```
-- AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ
AB -- BC BD BE BF BG BH BI BJ
AC BC -- CD CE CF CG CH CI CJ
AD BD CD -- DE DF DG DH DI DJ
AE BE CE DE -- EF EG EH EI EJ
AF BF CF DF EF -- FG FH FI FJ
AG BG CG DG EG FG -- GH GI GJ
AH BH CH DH EH FH GH -- HI HJ
AI BI CI DI EI FI GI HI -- IJ
AJ BJ CJ DJ EJ FJ GJ HJ IJ --
```

The next step up in speed could be multi-threading, but maybe this optimization already is good enough for your use case.

---

A multi-threaded implementation of the above could look like this (it's probably not *pythonic* in more ways than one, but it does the job):

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

# credit https://stackoverflow.com/a/54802737
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield n number of striped chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, n):
        yield l[i::n]

def calculate_travel_distance(a, b):
    return a + b

def calculate_distance_matrix(addresses):
    # prepare distance matrix, list of lists with n^2 slots
    distance_matrix = [['--' for a in addresses] for b in addresses]

    # the workload is the upper matrix triangle (where x < y)
    # since we're multi-threading, also remember the x,y position
    workload = [((a, b),(x, y)) for y, b in enumerate(addresses) for x, a in enumerate(addresses) if x < y]

    # worker function 
    def worker(chunk):
        return [(calculate_travel_distance(*points), matrix_pos) for points, matrix_pos in chunk]

    # distribute workload over available CPU cores
    pool = ThreadPool(cpu_count())
    result_chunks = pool.map(worker, chunks(workload, cpu_count()))

    # distribute result chunks into their slots
    for result_chunk in result_chunks:
        for result, matrix_pos in result_chunk:
            x, y = matrix_pos
            distance_matrix[x][y] = result
            distance_matrix[y][x] = result

    return distance_matrix

addresses = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
distaince_matrix = calculate_distance_matrix(addresses)

for row in distaince_matrix:
    print(' '.join(row))
```

It prints the same thing:

```
-- AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ
AB -- BC BD BE BF BG BH BI BJ
AC BC -- CD CE CF CG CH CI CJ
AD BD CD -- DE DF DG DH DI DJ
AE BE CE DE -- EF EG EH EI EJ
AF BF CF DF EF -- FG FH FI FJ
AG BG CG DG EG FG -- GH GI GJ
AH BH CH DH EH FH GH -- HI HJ
AI BI CI DI EI FI GI HI -- IJ
AJ BJ CJ DJ EJ FJ GJ HJ IJ --
```

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion, I agree we can reduce it to less than half here, it will not help if i compute distance using google distance api , there AB is not equal to BA since it is road distance, yes for crow(aerial) distance it is useful.

Comment: @ShashankTrivedi Oh, you're off-loading the distance calculation to Google? That's significant info, it should have been in the question. I thought you were using something like `geopy.distance.geodesic()`.

Comment: I am using geodesic, that is correct, I was saying AB and BA equal as long as it is geodesic. Here i am struggling only with the scale of the problem. Anyhow thanks for ur input.

Comment: @ShashankTrivedi I'm implementing a multithreaded extension to this approach, hang on.

Comment: @ShashankTrivedi Check the updated answer. This might provide another speed boost. Please measure and post how it compares with the other methods on your input data.

Comment: thank u very much, indeed it has significantly reduced execution time close to 80% for 300 locations.

Comment: @ShashankTrivedi So that means now it runs in 20% of the original time? That's not bad!