# How to create from an array multiple lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a numpy array: `np.array([0,  93,  94,  96, 228])`, which I need to split into multiple lists like:

```
[0,93]
[93,94]
[94,96]
[96,228]
```

How can I solve this in python?

Comment: This question may have been answered already.  Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483182/python-split-list-into-n-chunks/29679492 do what you need?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python split list into n chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483182/python-split-list-into-n-chunks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will do:

Firstly import [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/),

```
import numpy as np
```

Next, assign a variable to your [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) array,

```
a = np.array([ 0,  93,  94,  96, 228])
```

Create an empty list to store the desired output,

```
b=[]
```

Append elements and creating new lists,

```
for i in range(0, len(a)-1):
    b.append([a[i], a[i+1]])
```

And then the print the output

```
for each in b: 
    print(each)
```

Doing so, gives the desired output.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answear!

Comment: @KaterynaLubyk your welcome :)