# Create 3 lists from one list

Tags: python

I have a list that looks something like this (assume lists are NOT divisible by 3)

```
[26, 5, 20, 23, 19, 24, 16, 27, 21, 3, 2, 10, 9, 18, 25, 8, 0]
```

I would like to split the list into 3 lists `a`,`b`,`c`, that are approximately the same length. Is there a convenient way to do this?

Comment: Did you research this at all? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/24483182/3001761

Comment: This is the second time today that I wanted to close a question as a duplicate and @mozway was some seconds faster. ;)