# Python: How do we parallelize a python program to take advantage of a GPU server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gpu, multi-gpu, tesla

In our lab, we have **NVIDIA Tesla K80 GPU accelerator computing** with the following characteristics: `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v3 @2.30GHz, 48 CPU processors, 128GB RAM, 12 CPU cores`running under Linux 64-bit.

I am running the following code which does `GridSearchCV` after vertically appends different sets of dataframes into a single series of a `RandomForestRegressor` model. The two sample datasets I am considering are found in [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Iv8dfU4fTUcVR2Q2xQQzlvTWM)

```
import sys
import imp
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
import math
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer 
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import matplotlib
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error, make_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split


df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "cubic*.csv"))), ignore_index=True)
#df = pd.read_csv('cubic31.csv')

for i in range(1,3):
    df['X_t'+str(i)] = df['X'].shift(i)

print(df)

df.dropna(inplace=True)

X = (pd.DataFrame({ 'X_%d'%i : df['X'].shift(i) for i in range(3)}).apply(np.nan_to_num, axis=0).values)

X = df.drop('Y', axis=1)
y = df['Y']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.40)

X_train = X_train.drop('time', axis=1)
X_test = X_test.drop('time', axis=1)

#Fit models with some grid search CV=5 (not to low), use the best model
parameters = {'n_estimators': [10,30,100,500,1000]}
clf_rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1)
clf = GridSearchCV(clf_rf, parameters, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
model = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.cv_results_['params'][model.best_index_]
math.sqrt(model.best_score_*-1)
model.grid_scores_

#####
print()
print(model.grid_scores_)

print(math.sqrt(model.best_score_*-1))

#reg = RandomForestRegressor(criterion='mse')
clf_rf.fit(X_train,y_train)
modelPrediction = clf_rf.predict(X_test)
print(modelPrediction)

print("Number of predictions:",len(modelPrediction))

meanSquaredError=mean_squared_error(y_test, modelPrediction)
print("Mean Square Error (MSE):", meanSquaredError)
rootMeanSquaredError = sqrt(meanSquaredError)
print("Root-Mean-Square Error (RMSE):", rootMeanSquaredError)


####### to add the trendline
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#df.plot(x='time', y='Y', ax=ax)
ax.plot(df['time'].values, df['Y'].values)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
index_values=range(0,len(y_test))

y_test.sort_index(inplace=True)
X_test.sort_index(inplace=True)

modelPred_test = clf_rf.predict(X_test)
ax.plot(pd.Series(index_values), y_test.values)


PlotInOne=pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([pd.Series(modelPred_test), pd.Series(y_test.values)], axis=1))

plt.figure(); PlotInOne.plot(); plt.legend(loc='best')
```

When I run this program for a huge dataset (around 2 million rows), it is taking more than 3 days to do the `GridSearchCV`. I was, therefore, wondering if `Python` threads can utilize more than one CPU. How can we make this (or other `Python` programs) utilize more than one CPU so that it does the task faster in a short period of time? Thank you for any tips!

Comment: you can use `concurrent.futures` for either Multi Processing or Multi Threading, and theres also `PyCuda` to use the GPU

Comment: OK, thank you and I will read about it now. Do you by any chance have a reproducible example that I can reuse?

Comment: for which method? I listed 3, and have almost close to no experience working with `PyCuda`

Comment: I think going for `multiplrocessing` sounds better. I found one simple example in here: https://blog.dominodatalab.com/simple-parallelization/ . How can we pass all of the task I posted in the question as one or two functions?. I tried to put all my gridSearchCV task in one fucntion and call it, but it is giving me this error `TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable`

Comment: `concurrent.futures` is the same as multiprocessing. whatever function you create usually takes a single parameter as an input and you pass in an iterable as the argument. I don't have any examples with respect to machine learning, since I do not work in that field.

Comment: You are venturing towards distributed computing territory. For such purposes there are compute clusters. For example pyspark or Hadoop. Although 2 million rows is not a lot, I understand grid search will take time. You can use a smaller subsample of data and do grid search on that and use best hyperparameters to train on complete dataset or setup a compute cluster (or pay for a cloud one) and run your jobs on that. I am not an expert on distributed computing so I can't suggest any specifics. Also, try frameworks like xgboost that can use GPU unlike sklearn

Comment: Do not go into multiprocessing in python if you want to make use of many cores at once. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2yeB94CxVQ check out this video which explains in more detail cons of multiprocessing.

Comment: For a pure multiprocessing implementation, this answer gives exactly what's needed https://stackoverflow.com/a/25172338/5449226 . Given the use case, multiprocessing isn't a bad option.

Comment: It might be a better (but alternative) solution to change the file type if it does not have to be csv, then substituting panda's dataframe csv reading and writing with numpy's savetxt and loadtxt (while keeping all other things equal) will improve the running time drastically, whether there are many files, big files, or many big files.

Comment: It's unspecific. You should do a preliminary benchmark by yourself. How long does it take for ```clf.fit()``` or ```clf_rf.fit()```? Did you try the 'n_jobs' parameter of ```GridSearchCV```?

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try using "n_jobs=-1" in your existing GridSearchCV code first to enable parallel execution: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html