# Split a list of n floating point numbers into roughly equal lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a sorted list of n floating point numbers , and i want to split this list into m multiple lists in such a way that the sum of numbers in each list is roughly equal. Any thoughts?

I don't care how many numbers each list gets but the sum of numbers in each list should be fairly equal. One way that i have tried is to take subsections of the list equally (based on m) from the start and from the end and form a list , then shrink the existing list and repeat that process again.

I am fairly successful in that but the last list is either too heavier than others or too small than others , is there any better solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517051/split-a-list-of-numbers-into-n-chunks-such-that-the-chunks-have-close-to-equal/35517181 is this the same question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [splitting a list of arbitrary size into only roughly N-equal parts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130016/splitting-a-list-of-arbitrary-size-into-only-roughly-n-equal-parts)

Comment: @PRVS: nope. no sum there.