# How to split an array into n sub arrays so that their sum is equal

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist

I am having an array 
a = [10, 20,30, 15,15]
here I need to divide the array to n sub arrays such that their sum will be equal.
op: [[10,20],[30],[15,15]]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem (the wiki page describes the decision problem only...)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! Have a look on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) and what is a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will even have rewards at visiting those pages. We will not write code for you/do your home work. Share what you have tried so far and we will try to improve it.

Comment: Same problem can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517051/split-a-list-of-numbers-into-n-chunks-such-that-the-chunks-have-close-to-equal