# How to chunk any type of file in python and convert that file into string

Tags: python

How to chunk a file of any type into pieces and then converted it into string with the help of python?

I need to create a web app which runs on php as backend and when i upload a file in it... For safety it needs to split into N pieces of equal sizes and then convert it into strings so that it will be easy to transfer it to other storage drive

Comment: Please explain your problem in more details.

Comment: I need to create a web app which runs on php as backend and when i upload a file in it... For safety it needs to split into N pieces of equal sizes and then convert it into strings so that it will be easy to transfer it to other storage drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: For your updated question, it might be the easiest to use a library suited for this problem - [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) comes to mind here

Here's a chunkify from [Splitting a list of into N parts of approximately equal length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130016/splitting-a-list-of-arbitrary-size-into-only-roughly-n-equal-parts)

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
    """
    for i in range(0, len(l), n): # Use xrange if you're using Python 2 - it won't create the range list.
        yield l[i:i+n]
```

And to convert that to a string you could just use:

```
":".join(",".join(str(elem) for elem in chunk) for chunk in chunks(l, n))
```

For `l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` this prints:

```
>>> "1,2,3:4,5,6"
```

Comment: I dont need a list to be splited what i need is to split a file of any type(say pdf,xls,etc)

Comment: I'm not sure about pdfs (never had to deal with those, but you'd probably need to use some library); xls could be represented as a list of lists. What about using json messages?

Comment: how to use json messages for these???

Comment: See my edit, you're best off using a library.

Comment: Now i got it First i need to convert those as list(json) then chunck it Thanks!!!!

Comment: no worries, good luck!