# TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice' when running code in celery queue

Tags: python, redis, celery, celery-task

I'm having problems with the code bellow. I'm generating a list of lists using the chunk function. The code is adapted from here

[Splitting a list of into N parts of approximately equal length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130016/splitting-a-list-of-arbitrary-size-into-only-roughly-n-equal-parts)

Upon inspection in shell this is what i'm getting as types for the list and sublists.

```
In [18]: urls = list(range(957))

In [19]: type(urls)
Out[19]: list

In [20]: chunks = chunk(urls, 10)

In [21]: type(chunks)
Out[21]: list

In [22]: type(chunks[0])
Out[22]: list
```

They are all lists. But when i send this list to a celery task, it's throwing an error complaining that it's not a list, it's actually a slice.

This is the traceback:

```
[2016-10-03 12:30:57,360: ERROR/MainProcess] Task tasks.scrape_id_group[3759ff40-45f3-455f-87e7-1dadbbb201fc] raised unexpected: TypeError("unhashable type: 'slice'",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/milan/.virtualenvs/upwork/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/milan/.virtualenvs/upwork/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/milan/skilled/upwork/tasks.py", line 55, in scrape_id_group
    for i, sublist in enumerate(chunk(ids, count))
  File "/home/milan/skilled/upwork/utils.py", line 219, in chunk
    return [l[i::n] for i in range(n)]
  File "/home/milan/skilled/upwork/utils.py", line 219, in <listcomp>
    return [l[i::n] for i in range(n)]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

This is the modified code to show the problem:

```
from celery import Celery, group

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')

def chunk(l, n):
    return [l[i::n] for i in range(n)]

@app.task
def scrape_list_task(account, urls):
    print(urls)

@app.task
def scrape_id_task(account, ids):
    print(ids)

@app.task
def scrape_list_group():
    accounts = list(range(10))
    count = len(accounts)
    urls = list(range(957))
    return group(
        scrape_list_task.s(accounts[i], sublist)
        for i, sublist in enumerate(chunk(urls, count))
    )

@app.task
def scrape_id_group(ids):
    accounts = list(range(10))
    count = len(accounts)
    return group(
        scrape_id_task.s(accounts[i], sublist)
        for i, sublist in enumerate(chunk(ids, count))
    )

@app.task
def scrape_task():
    (scrape_list_group.s() | scrape_id_group.s())()
```

I'm running this code in the default celery queue with redis as a message broker. Any suggestions? Thanks!

EDIT:

The actual problem appears when running the scrape_task in a celery queue. When the scrape_list_group task is invoked with delay

```
scrape_list_group.delay()
```

the task runs fine

The problem seems to be chaining of the tasks. Tried to convert list to tuples, but no result with that as well. Thanks for any info!

SOLUTION:

I've changed the chunk code to an iterative approach. Thanks for the suggestion @Nf4r :)

```
def chunk(l, n):
    result = [[] for _ in range(n)]
    for i, el in enumerate(l):
        result[i % n].append(el)
    return result
```

Comment: Lists are not hashable objects because they are mutable. Instead of list, try to return tuple.

Comment: I've tried changing the chunk code to

`def chunk(l, n):
    return tuple([tuple(l[i::n]) for i in range(n)])`


This is what the shell reports:

`In [12]: type(chunks)
Out[12]: tuple

In [13]: type(chunks[0])
Out[13]: tuple`


Still same error @Nf4r

Comment: Obviously you can see that it's getting errors in list comprehension inside the chunk function. Can u try to use iterative-without comprehension way and check if it will work?

Comment: It is a celery related error. When i call the task like this scrape_list_group.delay() all is fine. when i try to chain two groups together (this tasks returns the results to another group), this is where i'm experiencing the error. Will update question to show more code. Thanks for the help