# How to split list into equal parts? Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have list like this `List = ['4', '4', '1', '2', '3', '2', '4', '1']` and i need to transform in list like `List = [["4","4"],['1','2'],['3','2'],['4','1']]`.

Comment: Try searching for similar questions before asking your own:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130016/splitting-a-list-into-n-parts-of-approximately-equal-length

Comment: Try something first before posting your question as an assignment to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

`itertools` provides a recipe, which can split an iterable into fixed-size blocks:

```py
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugly but it works...

```
def eqsplit(aList,partSize):
        return [aList[partSize*n:partSize*(n+1)] for n in range(0,int(len(aList)/partSize)+(1 if len(aList)%partSize else 0))]
```