# Get all pairs from a list which do not contains same element

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def get_pairs(some_list, limit):
    min = 2
    pair_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for x in range(min, limit+1):
        temp_list = list(itertools.combinations(some_list, x))
        pair_dict[x].append(temp_list)

    return pair_dict

z = get_pairs([1, 2, 3, 4], 4)
for key, value in z.items():
    print("Key: {}, Value: {}".format(key, value))
```

**Output:** 
Key: 2, Value: [[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]]
Key: 3, Value: [[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]]
Key: 4, Value: [[(1, 2, 3, 4)]]

But What I want is something like below

**Expected output:** 
Key: 2, Value: [[(1, 2), (3, 4)]] 
Key: 3, Value:[[(1, 2, 3)]] 
Key: 4, Value: [[(1, 2, 3, 4)]]

Comment: [splitting-a-list-into-n-parts-of-approximately-equal-lengt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130016/splitting-a-list-into-n-parts-of-approximately-equal-length)

Comment: [how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Comment: I originally duped to those, but removed the dupe again as your output is a dict not a list. Its only a 1-step from one to the other, but this kind of transfere thinking needed leads to ppl unduping the question anyhow.

Comment: why is `(2, 3, 4)` not in the `key = 3` list?

Answer (score 1):

If there should not be any overlap, don't even bother with combinations (they just overproduce and need to be filtered). Just go with consecutive slices:

```
def get_pairs(some_list, limit):
    pair_dict = {}

    for x in range(2, limit+1):
        pair_dict[x] = [(some_list[i:i+x]) for i in range(0, len(some_list)-x+1, x)]

    return pair_dict
```