# Splitting a python list into 4 sub-lists that are as even as possible

Tags: python, list, sublist

I'm trying to split a python list into four groups that are as even as possible, so for example, if the original list was `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`, then the resulting four sub-lists would be `[1, 5] [2,6] [3,7] [4,8]` where the code goes through each number in the original list and assigns them to a different group, and once it reaches group 4, it goes back to assigning to group 1.

If the original list is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` then the resulting four groups should be `[1,5,9] [2,6,10] [3,7] [4,8]` where two groups have 3 items, and the other two groups have 2 items--making the groups as even as possible.

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Comment: Answer is given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130016/splitting-a-list-into-n-parts-of-approximately-equal-length/37414115

Comment: @IsolatedSushi--doesn't that link produce different output than what's desired?

Comment: I don't see why this post has -5 score. This is a perfectly good question.

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget welcome to StackOverflow I guess :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it splits the input list into sublists in the round-robin fashion you desire:

```
def round_robin_sublists(l, n=4):
    lists = [[] for _ in range(n)]
    i = 0
    for elem in l:
        lists[i].append(elem)
        i = (i + 1) % n
    return lists

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
sublist = round_robin_sublists(l) # [[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7], [4, 8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [a[i::4] for i in range(4)]
[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7], [4, 8]]
```

Comment: Wait what is the `a[i::4]` part?