# split multiple dataframes into exactly 663 parts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to split a dataframe into exactly n parts, irrespective of size of the frame?

if I try:

```
n = int(len(df.index)/662) 
chunk_list = [df [ i : i+n ] for i in range(0, df.shape[0], n)]
```

I get some chunk_lists of size 663 and some of 664. How do I get all dataframes to split into exactly 663 parts?

Comment: Does your dataframe have rows that split exactly in to `663` parts? How would you split `df` with `10` rows by `3` - `3, 3, 4`. Maybe that is what is happening in your case.

Comment: If the total length of the dataframe is not divisible by 663, you'll have unequal parts

Comment: all the dataframes have like more than 100,000 rows. Not an issue in my case

Comment: @SuhasMucherla yes I sometimes get 664 dataframes. If anyone has any suggestions for a work around please let me know.

Comment: try np.split maybe : `np.split(df,663)`

Comment: What does this have to do with vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to resolve this. I referred [Splitting a list into N parts of approximately equal length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130016/splitting-a-list-into-n-parts-of-approximately-equal-length)

So I did

```
chunk_list = [df[(i*len(df.index))//663:((i+1)*len(df.index))//663] for i in range(663)]
```

and was able to resolve the issue