# Create sub-lists of the unique items from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I have a list with a pattern. For example. Items of the same kind in order.

```
mylist = [itemtype1, itemtype1, itemtype1, itemtype2, itemtype2, itemtype2, itemtype3, itemtype3, itemtype3]

myresultlist = [[itemtype1, itemtype2, itemtype3], [itemtype1, itemtype2, itemtype3], [itemtype1, itemtype2, itemtype3]]
```

Actually, I want to create sub-lists of the unique items.

```
[itemtype1, itemtype2, itemtype3], [itemtype1, itemtype2, itemtype3], [itemtype1, itemtype2, itemtype3]
```

Is it possible to create "myresultlist" from "mylist".

**Edit:**
Another example.

```
mylist = ['jimmy', 'andrew', 'kappy', 'US', 'Spain', 'UK', 'Baseball', 'Football', 'Cricket']

myresultlist = [['jimmy', 'US', 'Baseball'], ['andrew', 'Spain', 'Football'], ['kappy', 'UK', 'Cricket']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a list into N parts of approximately equal length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130016/splitting-a-list-into-n-parts-of-approximately-equal-length)

Comment: Are all unique items in list occurring  exactly same number of times? i.e. it itemtype1 appears 15 times, will itemtype2 and itemtype3 also appear exactly 15 times in mylist?

Comment: @Ashutosh Yes! exactly.

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 No, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @JimmyOppa: With the example in edit, it becomes tricky. Do you always know that there are exactly 3 set of elements, and they are repeated one after other in that order in mylist?

Comment: @Ashutosh Yes! There will always be 3 set of elements.
"mylist" can grow in length but the result will always have sets like ['jimmy', 'US', 'Baseball']

Yes, I know its a very tricky question. I couldn't solve it either, so I thought StackOverflow members might know regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little `range()` with a 3rd parameter and `zip()` gets you there I think...

```
# How many sub-sets to expect
subsets = 3

# your raw data
data = ['jimmy', 'andrew', 'kappy', 'US', 'Spain', 'UK', 'Baseball', 'Football', 'Cricket']

# reshape your raw data into the given number of "subsets"
data_subsets = [
    data[i:i+len(data)//subsets]
    for i in range(0, len(data), subsets)
]

# print your results
print([list(s) for s in zip(*data_subsets)])
```

This should give you:

```
[
    ['jimmy', 'US', 'Baseball'],
    ['andrew', 'Spain', 'Football'],
    ['kappy', 'UK', 'Cricket']
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
mylist = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]

[list(set(mylist))]*int((len(mylist)/len(set(mylist))))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

basically use set to deduplicate and then convert back to list. Repeat n number of times, where n = list length / set length

[Edit]
Saw the example in new edit of question. Above solution will not work for that scenario.