# How to separate a 10 digit number into 3 variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to take a 10 digit number and separate it into 3 different variables.

Also big help if you could suggest a way to do this to a multiple number list.

I was going too try a while loop but was looking for any other suggestions.

```
number = "1234567890"


#The output Im looking for

1 = 123
2 = 456
3 = 7890
```

Comment: research "string slicing"

Comment: I think the answer you are looking for might be here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2130016/7191879

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it very easily by converting your number into a string like this :

```
your_number = 1234567890

def split_in_3(number):
    number = str(number) # we convert the number into a string
    nb_list = []
    for i in range(2):
        nb_list.append(int(number[:3])) # we take the last three characters of our string and we put them into the list. Don't forget to convert them into integers
        number = number[3:] # we take off the last three digits of the nb and put it in the number variable
    nb_list.append(int(number)) # we add the final part (4 digits) to the list
    return nb_list

print(split_in_3(your_number))
```

You can return your splited numbers in a tuple or separatly, I did it with a list just as an example

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply like this:

```py
number = 1234567890

number = str(number)
a = number[:3]
b = number[3:6]
c = number[6:]
```