# How to assign each item in a list an equal amount of items from another list in python

Tags: python, python-itertools

Let's say I have a list of people

```
['foo','bar','baz']
```

and a list of items

```
['hat','bag','ball','bat','shoe','stick','pie','phone']
```

and I want to *randomly* assign each person an equal amount of items, like so

```
{
'foo':['hat','bat','stick'],
'bar':['bag','shoe','phone'],
'baz':['ball','pie']
}
```

I think `itertools` is the job for this, but I couldn't seem to find the right function as most itertools functions seem to just work on one object.

EDIT: Order does **not** matter. I just want to randomly assign each person an equal amount of items.

Comment: Does the order matter? Could it be `'foo': ['hat','bag','ball']`?

Comment: Good question. No, it doesn't. I'll edit OP to clarify this. If there are remainders (ie the last person getting 2 instead of 3 items) that is fine too.

Comment: `zip()` and `itertools.cycle()` will be useful. You need to cycle the list of people and zip that with the list of items.

Comment: And use either `random.shuffle` or `random.sample` to get the items randomized. The former modified the list in place, the latter returns a new list.

Comment: All of the approaches shown boil down to shuffling the items and then distributing them equally. The simplest approach to the latter is to split the list into chunks of the appropriate fixed size. Both of these problems are common duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution, using `itertools.cycle`:

```py
import random
from itertools import cycle

persons = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
items = ["hat", "bag", "ball", "bat", "shoe", "stick", "pie", "phone"]

random.shuffle(items)

out = {}
for p, i in zip(cycle(persons), items):
    out.setdefault(p, []).append(i)

print(out)
```

Prints (for example):

```
{
    "foo": ["phone", "pie", "bat"],
    "bar": ["bag", "stick", "hat"],
    "baz": ["shoe", "ball"],
}
```

---

If there could be fewer items than persons and each person should have key in output dictionary you can use:

```py
import random
from itertools import cycle

persons = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
items = ["hat", "bag", "ball", "bat", "shoe", "stick", "pie", "phone"]

random.shuffle(items)
random.shuffle(persons)  # to randomize who gets fewest items

out = {p: [] for p in persons}
for lst, i in zip(cycle(out.values()), items):
    lst.append(i)

print(out)
```

Comment: Another: `out = {p: items[i::len(p)] for i, p in enumerate(persons)}` (with help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2136090/12671057))

Answer (score 2):

You can shuffle the `items` and calculate a number of items for each person:

```
from itertools import islice
from random import shuffle

# https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched
def batched(iterable, n):
    # batched('ABCDEFG', 3) --> ABC DEF G
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError('n must be at least one')
    it = iter(iterable)
    while batch := tuple(islice(it, n)):
        yield batch

people = ['foo','bar','baz']
items = ['hat','bag','ball','bat','shoe','stick','pie','phone']

shuffle(items)
b = batched(items, ((len(items)-1) // len(people))+1)

output = {k:list(next(b)) for k in people}
print(output)
```

Sample output:

`{'foo': ['phone', 'bat', 'ball'], 'bar': ['hat', 'bag', 'pie'], 'baz': ['stick', 'shoe']}`

btw `batched()` is available in python 3.12

However, as Kelly Bundy points out, `batched()` doesn't always split evenly.

This `split()` function I found in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2135920) to another question works better:

```
def split(a, n):
    k, m = divmod(len(a), n)
    return (a[i*k+min(i, m):(i+1)*k+min(i+1, m)] for i in range(n))

b = split(items, len(people))
output = {k:list(next(b)) for k in people}
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

people = ['foo','bar','baz']
items = ['hat','bag','ball','bat','shoe','stick','pie','phone']

# set up a dictionary with values as a list so we can append to it
out = defaultdict(list)
# get a list of indexes for the items in the list
item_indexes = [i for i in range(len(items))]
# ... then shuffle these into random order
random.shuffle(item_indexes)

# Now loop over the randomized indexes, 
for i in item_indexes:
    # ... and pick an item from the list based on that index.
    out[people[i%len(people)]].append(items[i])

pprint(out)
```

Result:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'bar': ['bag', 'phone', 'shoe'],
             'baz': ['stick', 'ball'],
             'foo': ['bat', 'hat', 'pie']})
```

Comment: what if I don't know how many items should be distributed to each person? Would I need to find away around hardcoding the modulo 3?

Comment: I fixed that already. Used len(people) instead.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
g=(i for i in ['hat','bag','ball','bat','shoe','stick','pie','phone']) #generator
keys=['foo','bar','baz']
d={k: [] for k in keys}
while True:
    try:
        for i in keys:
            d[i].append(next(g)) 
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Version with randomization: Draw random key and use generator for values.

```
import random
g=(i for i in ['hat','bag','ball','bat','shoe','stick','pie','phone'])
keys=['foo','bar','baz']
d={k: [] for k in keys}
while True:
    try:
        i = random.randint(0, len(keys)-1)
        d[keys[i]].append(next(g)) 
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Comment: Second piece of code outputs `{'foo': ['bag', 'ball'], 'bar': ['bat', 'shoe', 'stick', 'phone'], 'baz': ['hat', 'pie']}` - it can't guarantee that each person gets the same number of items.

Comment: I know, It may be handy if items are from stream and shuffle() needs to receive all. Even accepted answer will not guarantee same number if len(items)%3 != 0

Comment: In this case, it will make sure that all receive the same amount, except the last one who gets what is left, which is what to OP wants as explained in a comment. Your solution doesn't guarantee anything (see the output of my first run of your code, 'bar' got 4 items).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice simple one-liner solution that you can easily change for your needs:

```
import random

people: list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
items: list = ['hat', 'bag', 'ball', 'bat', 'shoe', 'stick', 'pie', 'phone']

random.shuffle(items)
result: dict = {p: i for p, i in zip(people, [items[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(items), 3)])}

print(result)
```